# Where to find/how to create a SSL Certificate

Tags: c++, boost, openssl

Where to find/how to create a SSL Certificate to use it with openssl in order to communicate with gmail? I am trying to use boost asio and open ssl libraries together in order to send an email from a gmail account to another using port 587 and server smtp.gmail.com.

Comment: [you probably find your answer here][1][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-build-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537016/how-to-use-boost-asio-c