# What happens when an async_write() operation never ends and there is a strand involved?

Tags: windows, asynchronous, timeout, boost-asio

I know that the next **async_write()**'s should be performed when the previous one finished (with or without errors, but when it finished).

I would like to know what happens when, while making async_write() calls, if one of these takes long time for some reason or even never ends (I assume there is no timeouts here like in synchronous operations). **When** this operation will be considered as failed? **When** that operation that never ends is finally removed by the OS internally?
Maybe, are there timeouts involved and my assumptions are wrong?

I mean, the write operation is sent to the OS and could possibly block, indefinitely?
So the handler is never called and the next async_write()'s are never called.

NOTE: I am assuming that we are calling run() in **several threads** but the write operations should be **sent in order** so I am also assuming that the write handlers are wrapped with a **strand**.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I may of course be wrong, but except in a very contrieved example, I don't think that there is any such as thing as a write blocking forever. Writes usually go into a buffer. If no buffer is free, it blocks, OK, fine. But unless the computer is frozen in liquid nitrogen or something, eventually some buffer _must_ become free. The only things that are "indefinite" that I could imagine would be pulling the network cable for a socket, or pulling an USB stick out (with buffered writes disabled) but that would fail early with an error... so again it's not "indefinite".

Answer (score 0):

There are no explicit timeouts for asynchronous operations, but they can be cancelled through the IO object's `cancel()` member function.  These operations will be considered as having failed only when the underlying OS call itself fails in a manner where a retry cannot reasonable occur.  For example, if the write fails from:

- `EINTR`, then the write will immediately be reattempted.
- `EWOULDBLOCK`, `EAGAIN`, or `ERROR_RETRY`, then Boost.Asio will push the operation back into the job queue.  This could occur if the write buffer was full, so pushing the operation back into the queue defers its reattempt, allowing other operations to be attempted.
- Other errors will cause the operation to fail.

There should not be an indefinitely block in the system call.  Boost.Asio sets the underlying IO objects to non-blocking, and provides synchronous blocking writes behavior by waiting on the associated file descriptor if a write failed with `EWOULDBLOCK`, `EAGAIN`, or `ERROR_RETRY`.

A strand is not affected by long term asynchronous operations.  Strands are used to provide strict sequential invocation of handlers, not the operations themselves.  In the case of composed operations, such as [`boost::asio::async_write`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write.html), the intermediate handlers will also be invoked through the same strand as the final handler.  Overall, this behavior helps provide thread safety, as:

- All `async_write_some` operations initiated from intermediate handlers are within the strand.
- The operation itself is not within the strand.  This allows other for other handlers to run while the actual write is occurring.
- The user handler will be invoked within the strand.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/#12801042) may provide some more insight into composed operations and strands.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. I have just realized about that detail where strands just provide sequential invocation of handlers, not the operations themselves. It would be interesting to know how many times an operation is pushed back into the job queue when EAGAIN or similar happens before giving it up.