# asio strand and data synchronization

Tags: boost-asio

I found that asio's doc about synchronization by `strand` is obscure. It just says that in a thread pool design asio app, the handler can be run in any thread which had call `io_service::run()`. Using a `strand` to warp these handler can make their execution concurrent correctly. In its [example3](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server3/connection.cpp), all `handle_read` are wrap by `strand`, and I think the variables in `Connection` class such as `buffer` has been synchronized by `strand`, different thread calls `handle_read` will gets up-to-date data, that is OK. But what about there is a data member defined in `Connection` class which also accessed by a handler was not wrap by `strand`? I think this is a problem, isn't it?

In its doc [example3](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server3/server.cpp), why `handle_accept` was not wrap by a `strand`? The `new_connection_` is accessed by multi threads: `new_connection_.reset` called by thread A and `server::handle_accept` called by thread B. I think it needs data synchronization here or else thread B might use a out-of-date `new_connection_` that its reset have not been called yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTTP Server 3](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server3/connection.cpp)  is designed in such a way that it does not actually need a `strand`.

A fundamental trait of Boost.Asio is that a handler will be called at most once for a given operation.  This behavior allows for the call path of asynchronous programming to be envisioned more as a call chain.

For example, examine the illustrated call chain for the `server` accepting connections:

```
server::server(...)
{
  start_accept();  --.
}                    |
    .----------------'
    |      .----------------------------------------.
    V      V                                        |
void server::start_accept()                         |
{                                                   |
  new_connection_.reset(new connection(...));       |
  acceptor_.async_accept(..., handle_accept);  --.  |
}                                                |  |
    .--------------------------------------------'  |
    |                                               |
    V                                               |
void server::handle_accept(...)                     |
{                                                   |
  if (!error)                                       |
  {                                                 |
    new_connection_->start();                       |
  }                                                 |    
  start_accept();  ---------------------------------'
}
```

As shown in the illustration, only a single asynchronous event chain is present.  With no possibility of concurrent execution of the handlers or operations on `new_connection`, it is said to be running in an implicit strand.  The thread in which the handler, `server::handle_accept`, runs is inconsequential.

The `connection::handle_read` call chains and more details about strands are answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/#12801042) question.

Comment: I get 2 points: 1, A chain of handler calling is concurrent OK in asio as the doc said "implicit strand". 2, HTTP example 3's handle_read is unnecessary to wrap in strand because it makes up a chain. Am I right?

Comment: @jean: In the illustrated chain, there is a single chain of asynchronous operations associated with `acceptor_`.  Thus, there is no possibility of concurrent execution of the handlers associated with this chain.  On the other hand, these handlers may be running concurrently with the handlers of another chain, such as each `connection`'s `handle_read`.  And yes, the `strand` in `handle_read` is not necessary because the chain forms an implicit strand.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are somehow missing the meaning of **strand**. *It does not synchronize data access.* It syncronize handler calls. This can be understood as "all handlers wrapped by given **strand** will NOT be called concurrently".

So, your first questsion: if some handler is not wrapped by strand - it can be called concurrently now. So its subject to sync issues and/or RC. Note if you wrap in one place does not mean you are protected from RC; this should be done in every call. Since strand does not know what you calling from other thread unless you use `.wrap`

Second question: In given example **start_accept** setting up accept handler **handle_accept**, and **handle_accept** is setting new accept handler (via calling **start_accept**). So, they will not be called concurrently since you cannot create 2 or more **async_accept** events. Sure, if other thread call **start_accept** for same "Server" instance -  this example can/will fail, but doing so is a clear mistake.

Comment: I my experience, thread synchronization means both of data and code execution. Lack of any one, the synchronization will be meaningless. Because lock can achieve both of them. In example, if strand don't make data synchronization, the buffer data member will be problematic. start_accept() & handle_accept() will be executed in different threads, so why there is nothing to do with data sync with data member 'new_connection_'?

Comment: start_accept() & handle_accept() cannot be executed both. When `start_accept` is running, there is no active `async_accept`, so `handle_accept` cannot be called. On other side, when `handle_accept` is called, there is no more such handler in the io_service; it will be added at the end of `handle_accept` when you call `async_accept()`. However, there is a bug. Since `new_connection_->start()` is not saving `new_connection_` shared_ptr, it will be rewritten in `async_accept`. So you right, this can fail, but in some other place(in connection class). Note this is incomplete examaple

Comment: I know they will not execute at same time by different thread. My question is when thread A call handle_accept() AFTER thread B complete start_accept() execution, how to synchronize the shared variable 'new_connection_' states. Because thread B calls 'new_connection_' reset() that will change it's state. Without any explicit sync, how those state changing can be seen by thread A?

Comment: Since `start_accept()` is designed to start only once from outside and many times from inside of object, `new_connection_.reset()` will called only when `handle_accept` is ready to do so; and in same thread. If some thread call `start_accept()` when this instance already run, its will be trouble. But doing so is user mistake.