# Correct usage of asio::io_service::strand?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Here is my code:

```
void client_connection::serve()
{
    asio::async_read(this->socket_, asio::buffer(&buffer_, buffer_.size()),

        // predicate/condition (do I wrap this?)
        std::bind(&client_connection::handle_read_predicate, this->shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2),

        // handler
        this->strand_.wrap(std::bind(&client_connection::handle_read, this->shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)));
}

std::size_t client_connection::handle_read_predicate(const asio::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_)
{
    // useless flawed function, for now

    // std::cout << "test: reached predicate, " << bytes_ << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

void client_connection::handle_read(const asio::error_code& error_, std::size_t bytes_)
{
    // useless flawed function, for now

    if (error_) return;

    this->serve();
}
```

My question is whether it would be correct usage of asio::io_service::strand to wrap the predicate/condition handler with the same strand_ object; if so, why, and if not, please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to wrap it in the strand.

Per the [strand](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html) documented, for composed operations, such as the `async_read` free function, all intermediate handlers are invoked within the handler's strand.  A side-effect of this is that all intermediate invocations of the `CompletionCondition` are also invoked from within the strand.

However, make sure to dispatch the initial invocation of `client_connection::serve()` within a strand when starting the asynchronous loop, as the initial `CompletionCondition` and asynchronous read socket operation occur within the context of the caller.  For example, in the following illustration, all calls to `socket.async_read()`, `client_connection::handle_read_predicate()`, and `client_connection::handle_read()` will occur within the strand:

```
void client_connection::start()
{
  strand_.dispatch(std::bind(&client_connection::serve,
                             shared_from_this())) --------.
}                                                         |
    .-----------------------------------------------------'
    |  .--------------------------------------------------.
    V  V                                                  |
void client_connection::serve()                           |
{                                                         |
  async_read(socket_, buffer,                             |
    std::bind(&client_connection::handle_read_predicate,  |
              this),                                      |
    strand_.wrap(                                         |
      std::bind(&client_connection::handle_read,          |
                shared_from_this())); --.                 |
}                                       |                 |
    .-----------------------------------'                 |
    V                                                     |
void client_connection::handle_read(...)                  |
{                                                         |
  if (error) return;                                      |
  serve();  ----------------------------------------------'
}
```

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I could remove the strand_.wrap from the example above and change the first strand_.dispatch to a strand_.wrap with no issues?

Comment: @kvanberendonck: No.  `strand::wrap()` only creates a handler, neither the provided handler nor returned handler are dispatched or posted to the `io_service`.  Replacing the `strand_.dispatch` would result in a no-op.  The `strand_.dispatch` serializes the execution of the first `socket_.async_read()` and `handle_read_predicate`; while `strand_.wrap()` serializes all other `socket_.async_read()` calls, `handle_read`, and `handle_read_predicate` in the `server()` -> `handle_read()` asynchronous chain.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12801042/1053968) answer for more details.