# boost.asio compound operations in single and multi threaded processes

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

There are several things about boost.asio compound operations that are not clear from the official documentation and various threads that I have read on the topic.

**The Scenario**

Two `boost::asio::async_write` requests A and B are scheduled on a single TCP socket.

**Questions**

1. In a single-threaded process, can it happen that A is executed concurrently with B? Namely, intermediate calls to `async_write_some` of A are mixed with those of B (which essentially renders a corrupted stream)?
2. If the answer to (1) is Yes, does `io_service::strand` solve the issue in single-threaded process? Does it assure that all intermediate calls of A complete before B is started?
3. Does `io_service.strand` solve the issue of (1) in a multi-threaded process, when more than one thread execute `io_service::run()`? Does it assure that all intermediate calls of A complete before B is started?

Comment: Documentation is very clear, really.  It may look unclear, but this is because of some "unclear topics" in your mind, proactor pattern for example ! Anyway one of the topnotch SO Question/Answer that helps me on my own learning curve is [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568100/confused-when-boostasioio-service-run-method-blocks-unblocks?rq=1).

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7756894/1053968) provides a solution to the scenario by using a queue to serialize multiple `async_write()` operations, and processing the queue with an asynchronous call chain within a [`strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html), fulfilling both the requirements of `async_write()` and the stream's thread safety.

Answer (score 2):

The documentations states explicitly: ["The program must ensure that the stream performs no other write operations (such as async_write, the stream's async_write_some function, or any other composed operations that perform writes) until this operation completes."](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html)

So, multiple `async_write`'s must never be called concurrently. In a single-threaded case, one can chain them, calling a subsequent `async_write` in the completion hanndler of the previous one.

If `io_service::run` is run in multiple threads, just wrap `async_write`'s completion handler by a `strand`, and Asio [will synchronize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875359/correct-usage-of-asioio-servicestrand) all the intermediate internal handlers.

Comment: I believe "calling a subsequent async_write in the completion handler of the previous one" also solves the multithreaded case without having to wrap the handler

Comment: @igor-r is your asnwer 1. Yes 2. No.No 3. No.No ?

Comment: @rbk Yes, if by saying "can it happen..." you mean "can it happen, if misused...".