# When do I have to use io_service::strand

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

When do I have to use `io_service::strand`?

From the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) it seems that I need it when I want to prevent several handlers to be executed concurrently:

> The io_service::strand class provides the ability to post and dispatch
>   handlers with the guarantee that none of those handlers will execute
>   concurrently

As far as I know, this can happen if I have several threads calling `run` on the same `io_service` object.

So, from this point of view, it seems that the only reasonable way to use `strand` is when we have some shared memory **inside** our handlers passed to the `io_service::post` function and we don't want to use any synchronization primitives like `boost::mutex` inside them for some reason. Am I right?

Or is there any internal `io_service` problems with having two threads calling `io_service::run` concurrently?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875359/correct-usage-of-asioio-servicestrand) helps.

Comment: @mkaes Well, that question is about specific `boost::asio` functions like `async_read` and `async_write`. My question is about more general stuff related to the `io_service`

Comment: Maybe this is [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042) is more relevant?

Comment: FrozenHeart: the docs are very clear that most (non-special) operations on io_service are threadsafe. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.thread_safety