# When do I have to use boost::asio:strand

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

Reading the document of boost::asio, it is still not clear when I need to use  asio::strand. Suppose that I have one thread using  io_service is it then safe to write on a socket as follows ?

```
void Connection::write(boost::shared_ptr<string> msg)
{
    _io_service.post(boost::bind(&Connection::_do_write,this,msg));
}

void Connection::_do_write(boost::shared_ptr<string> msg)
{
    if(_write_in_progress)
    {
      _msg_queue.push_back(msg);
    }
    else
    {
      _write_in_progress=true;
      boost::asio::async_write(_socket, boost::asio::buffer(*(msg.get())),
      boost::bind(&Connection::_handle_write,this,
             boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
}

void Connection::_handle_write(boost::system::error_code const &error)
{
  if(!error)
  {
    if(!_msg_queue.empty())
    {
          boost::shared_ptr<string> msg=_msg_queue.front();
      _msg_queue.pop_front();
      boost::asio::async_write(_socket, boost::asio::buffer(*(msg.get())),
           boost::bind(&Connection::_handle_write,this,
                   boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
    else
    {
      _write_in_progress=false;
    }
  }
}
```

Where multiple threads calls Connection::write(..) or do I have to use asio::strand ?

Answer (score 25):

Short answer: no, you don't have to use a `strand` in this case.

Broadly simplificated, an `io_service` contains a list of function objects (handlers). Handlers are put into the list when `post()` is called on the service. e.g. whenever an asynchronous operation completes, the handler and its arguments are put into the list.  `io_service::run()` executes one handler after another. So if there is only one thread calling `run()` like in your case, there are no synchronisation problems and no `strand`s are needed.
Only if multiple threads call `run()` on the same `io_service`, multiple handlers will be executed at the same time, in N threads up to N concurrent handlers. If that is a problem, e.g. if there might be two handlers in the queue at the same time that access the same object, you need the `strand`.
You can see the `strand` as a kind of lock for a group of handlers. If a thread executes a handler associated to a `strand`, that `strand` gets locked, and it gets released after the handler is done. Any other thread can execute only handlers that are not associated to a locked `strand`.

***Caution:*** this explanation may be over-simplified and technically not accurate, but it gives a basic concept of what happens in the `io_service` and of the `strand`s.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `io_service::run()` from only one thread will cause all event handlers to execute within the thread, regardless of how many threads are invoking `Connection::write(...)`.  Therefore, with no possible concurrent execution of handlers, it is safe.  The documentation refers to this as an [implicit strand](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html).

On the other hand, if multiple threads are invoking `io_service::run()`, then a strand would become necessary.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12801042/1053968) answer covers strands in much more detail.