# boost asio - SSL async_read and async_write from one thread

Tags: c++, boost, ssl, openssl, boost-asio

I know that OpenSSL, boost asio SSL implementation is based on, doesn't allow concurrent SSL_read() and SSL_write() (i.e. SSL_read() and SSL_write() executed by different threads).

Is it safe to call boost asio async_read() and async_write() on SSL socket from the same thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The requirement for [`boost::asio::ssl:::stream`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream.html) is for thread safety; it does not place a requirement as to which thread may initiate operations:

> Distinct objects: Safe.
>
> Shared objects: Unsafe. The application must also ensure that all asynchronous operations are performed within the same implicit or explicit strand.

If the application only has one thread processing the `io_service`, and `async_read()` and `async_write()` are initiated from within that thread, then it is safe, as the operation and completion handler(s) are running within an implicit strand.

On the other hand, if multiple threads are processing the `io_service`, then an explicit `strand` is necessary.  The `async_read()` and `async_write()` operations need to be initiated from within a `strand`, and the completion handlers need to be wrapped by the same `strand`.

For more details on Boost.Asio's thread safety requirements, `strands`, and composed operations, consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12801042/1053968) answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is safe to *call* `async_read()` and `async_write()` on SSL socket from the same thread, but in general case **it is not enough** to avoid concurrency issues with ssl::stream. The actual requirement is provided in [`ssl::stream` documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream.html):

> Thread Safety (...) Shared objects: Unsafe. The application must also ensure that all asynchronous operations are performed within the same implicit or explicit strand.

Of course, the standard boost::asio requirement to ensure that:

- no other read operations are performed until `async_read` handler gets
  called, and
- no other write operations are performed until `async_write` handler gets called.

must also be met.

Note, that it is allowed to schedule a read operation while a write operation is underway and conversely. Simultaneous asynchronous read and write operations are possible in `ssl::stream` thanks to handling OpenSSL's network needs asynchronously through [`BIO`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bio.html) mechanism. `SSL_read()` and `SSL_write()` manifest their needs to communicate by returning `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` and `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` error codes. These error codes are used by `ssl::stream` implementation to schedule the network operations asynchronously. A read or write operation on `ssl::stream` may need multiple both read and write operations on the underlying network socket and multiple calls to `SSL_read()` / `SSL_write()`, which will be performed from asynchronous network operation completion handlers (particularly not from the original `async_read`/`async_write` call), this is why it is not enough to ensure that `async_read` and `async_write` are not called simultaneously, but a strand is needed.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe. But simulateous 2 or more `async_write`-s on same socket are unsafe and will segfault often(at least for SSL case).

Comment: It won't segfault, it will interleave data.

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing this is to construct the `ssl::stream` using a strand as it's execution context. You can then perform `async_read` and `async_write` operations from that strand. Both of these operations can be scheduled at the same time.

You just have to make sure that the context the stream was constructed with and the context that  `async_read` and `async_write` are called from are effectively an explicit or implicit strand.

Related question: [boost asio ssl async_read + async_write within a strand is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74186642/boost-asio-ssl-async-read-async-write-within-a-strand-is-failing)