# C++ shared_ptr and threadsanitazer reporting data race

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio, shared-ptr, thread-sanitizer

this is a paste from threadsanitazer (clang) which reports data race
http://pastebin.com/93Gw7uPi

Googling around it seems this is a problem with threadsanitazer (for example http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57507)

So lets say this looks like (written by hand just now  for this so it's not working code):

```
class myclass : : public std::enable_shared_from_this<myclass>
{
  public:  // example!
  myclass(boost::asio::io_service &io, int id);
  ~myclass() { /*im called on destruction properly*/ }
  void start_and_do_async();
  void stop();

  int ID;
  boost::asio::udp::socket usocket_;
  ... endpoint_;
  ... &io_;
}

typedef std::shared_ptr<myclass> myclass_ptr;
std::unordered_map<int, myclass_ptr> mymap;

myclass::myclass(boost::asio::io_service io, int id) : io_(io)
{
  ID = id;
}

void myclass::start_and_do_async()
{
   // do work here 

  //passing (by value) shared_ptr from this down in lambda prolongs this instance life
  auto self(shared_from_this()); 
  usocket_.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(...),endpoint,
  [this,self](const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    start_and_do_async();
  }
}

void myclass::stop()
{ 
  // ...some work and cleanups
  usocket_.close();
}
```

in main thread new thread is created (this is in another class actually) and run for new io_service handlers

```
new boost::thread([&]()
{   
     boost::asio::io_service::work work(thread_service);
     thread_service.run();
});
```

and from the main thread element gets added or removed periodically

```
void add_elem(int id)
{
  auto my = std::make_shared<my>(thread_service, id);
  my->start();
  mymap[id] = my;
}

void del_elem(int id)
{ 
  auto my = mymaps.at(id);
  mymap.erase(id); //erase first shared_ptr instace from map

  // run this in the same thread as start_and_do_async is running so no data race can happen (io_service is thread safe in this case)
  thread_service.post[my]()
  {
    my.stop(); //this will finally destroy myclass and free memory when shared_ptr is out of scope
  });
}
```

So in this case and judging by the docs (where it states that distinct shared_ptr (boost or std) allows read/write access from multiple threads) can there be a data race?

Does this code properly create two distinct shared_ptr instaces for one pointer?

In shared_ptr.h I can see atomic operations so I just want a confirmation that it is problem  with thread sanitazer reporting false positives.

In my tests this works correctly with no memory leakage (shared_ptr instances are removed properly and destructor is called), segfaults or anything else (10 hours inserting/deleting elements - 100 per second or 1 by second)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `shared_ptr` thread safety documentation matches its implementation, then the report of a data race on the `shared_ptr` is a false-positive.  The threads operate on distinct instances of `shared_ptr` that share ownership of the same instance.  Hence, there is no concurrent access of the same `shared_ptr` instance.

With that said, I do want to stress that in the example, the thread safety of `myclass::usocket_` is dependent on only a single thread processing the `io_service`, effectively executing in an implicit [strand](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html).  If multiple threads service the `io_service`, then an explicit [`strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) can be used to provide thread safety.  For more details on some of the thread safety subtleties with Boost.Asio and `strands`, consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12801042/1053968) answer.

Comment: Yes, there is only one thread processing that io_service, for all those reasons you wrote. I do understand the principle in the example, but here I actually wasn't completely sure if two shared_ptr instaces are properly created and deleted with del_elem function. Could you confirm this before accepting your answer? (using boost::make_shared and boost::shared_ptr instead throws Exception: bad_weak_ptr so that left me wondering even though I haven't properly tried to debug what could be the problem)

Comment: @juzerKicker Although the map returns `shared_ptr<myclass>&`, `auto` will deduce `my` type to `shared_ptr<myclass>` rather than a reference, so a copy is made.  Also, the lambda capturing by value creates another `shared_ptr` copy whose lifetime ends almost immediately after the completion handler has been invoked.  If `bad_weak_ptr` is being thrown during `make_shared`, then `shared_from_this()` is likely being invoked from within the constructor violating the precondition that at least one `shared_ptr` instance owns the object.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for explanation (I've seen reported problems when calling shared_from_this from constructor and object is nonexistent but this is not in my case. However I haven't properly tested that case. I've probably mixed boost and std somewhere regarding shared_ptr and it doesn't play nicely)

Comment: Did you mean that shared pointer can be used to avoid data race among threads to access the same variable on the heap?