# Is ip::tcp::socket.close() thread safe?

Tags: c++11, boost-asio

If there is a `async_read` on the socket ongoing, there should be a internal thread of `io_service` checking the status of the socket. Is it safe to call `socket.close()` from another thread (maybe when it is running a separate handler of the `io_service`)?

I mean even I can guarantee that my handlers will not use the asio `socket` concurrently, is it good enough (when taking the internal threads of `io_service` into consideration)?

**Update:**
I am using `async_read` in a stackful coroutine. Quite similar to the example at the bottom of [this doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/spawn.html), except that mine has an extra layer of function calling with the `yield_context`. If I dispatch the `socket.close()` operation in `my_strand` in that example, is the whole thing thread safe? In another word, will all concerned operations (`async_read`, intermediate `async_read_some`, implicit handlers of the stackful coroutine, `socket.close()`) run through a single strand `my_strand`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In general, it is unsafe to make concurrent calls to the same socket object<sup>1</sup>.  The [`async_read()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html) composed operation is composed of zero or more intermediate [`async_read_some()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html) operations.  These intermediate operations are only initiated in threads that are currently calling `io_service::run()`.  The internal threads are fairly transparent, and none of the threads listed in the [Platform-Specific Implementation Notes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/implementation.html) will present a problem.

Therefore:

- If a single thread is invoking `io_service::run()` and `socket.close()` is invoked from within a handler, then it is safe as there is no possibility of concurrent execution.  The documentation refers to this as an implicit strand.
- If a single thread is invoking `io_service::run()` and `socket.close()` is invoked from outside of a handler, then it is unsafe, as `socket` may have two concurrent calls:  `close()` from outside of the `io_service` and `async_read_some()` from a thread that is currently calling `io_service::run()`.  To make it thread safe, post a handler into the `io_service` that invokes `socket.close()`.
- If multiple threads are invoking `io_service::run()`, then an explicit [strand](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html) is required to guarantee thread safety.  The `async_read()` needs to be initiated from within a [`strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html), and its completion handler must also be [wrapped](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/wrap.html) by the same strand.  Furthermore, `socket.close()` should be [dispatched](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/dispatch.html) through the strand.

For stackful coroutines, using the [`spawn()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/spawn/overload3.html) overload that accepts a `strand` will execute the provided function within the context of the `strand`.  Furthermore, when the `yield_context` object is passed as the handler to asynchronous operations, the handlers, including intermediate handlers from composed operations, are invoked within the context of the `strand`.  Hence, to ensure thread safety, `socket.close()` must either be:

- invoked within the coroutine:

  ```
  // The lambda will execute within the context of my_strand.
  boost::asio::spawn(my_strand,
    [socket&](boost::asio::yield_context yield)
    {
      // In my_strand.
      // ...

      // The socket.async_read_some() operations that composed async_read()
      // will run within the context of my_strand.
      async_read(socket, ..., yield);

      // Still within my_strand.
      socket.close();
    });
  ```
- explicitly dispatched on `my_strand`:

  ```
  // The lambda will execute within the context of my_strand.
  boost::asio::spawn(my_strand,
    [socket&](boost::asio::yield_context yield)
    {
      // In my_strand.
      // ...

      // The socket_.async_read_some() operations that composed async_read()
      // will run within the context of my_strand.
      async_read(socket, ..., yield);
    });

  my_strand.dispatch([socket&](){ socket.close(); });
  ```

For more details on thread safety, composed operations, and strands, consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12801042/1053968) answer.

---

<sub>1. The [revision history](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html#boost_asio.history.asio_1_4_0___boost_1_37) documents an anomaly to this rule.  If supported by the OS, *synchronous* read, write, accept, and connection operations are thread safe.  I an including it here for completeness, but suggest using it with caution.</sub>

Comment: Wow! Very professional answer! My situation concerns stackful coroutine. I added that part in my quesiton. Please take a look.

Comment: @updogliu Glad the answer was helpful.  I have updated it to cover stackful coroutines.

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer is worth incorporating to ASIO documentation!