# Multiple Http Servers with Poco and Boost C++

Tags: c++, boost-asio, poco, poco-libraries

I'm trying to create multiple Http servers with Poco::Net and Boost libraries, but is occurring the following error internally in Poco file *Application.cpp*:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Assertion violation: _pInstance == 0 [in file "src/Application.cpp", line 115]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

I'm using the code below:

```
#include <Poco/Net/HTMLForm.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPServerRequest.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPServerResponse.h>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>

boost::asio::io_service service(100);

class RequestHandler : public Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler {
public:
    RequestHandler(){}
    void handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request, Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse& response){}
};

class RequestHandlerFactory : public Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandlerFactory {
public:
    RequestHandlerFactory(){}
    Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler* createRequestHandler(const Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request)
    {
        return new RequestHandler();
    }
};

class HttpServer :
        public Poco::Util::ServerApplication,
        public boost::enable_shared_from_this<HttpServer>{

    Poco::Net::ServerSocket svs;
    Poco::Net::HTTPServer srv;

public:
    HttpServer(std::string address_, Poco::UInt16 port_):
        svs(Poco::Net::SocketAddress(address_.empty() ? "127.0.0.1" : address_, port_)),
        srv(new RequestHandlerFactory(), svs, new Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams)
    {
        svs.setReuseAddress(true);
        svs.setReusePort(true);
    }

    virtual ~HttpServer(){}

    void start()
    {
        service.post(
            boost::bind(&HttpServer::exec, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void stop()
    {
        srv.stop();
    }

private:
    void exec()
    {
        srv.start();
        waitForTerminationRequest();
        srv.stop();
    }    
};
```

This is the main code of server, and Im creating the servers at main function for example.
The *service.post* call, is for asynchronous call of method *exec* and the construction of *service(100)* refers to a thread pool of size 100.

The server is created as follows:

```
boost::shared_ptr<HttpServer> server(
        new HttpServer("", 8080));

boost::shared_ptr<HttpServer> server2(
        new HttpServer("", 8181));

server->start();
server2->start(); // Error occurs here
```

The error is shown when the second server is started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpServerApplication` is not designed to be used in this way. It's designed to be a singleton.

> http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Util.ServerApplication.html

You can fix that part by not deriving from `ServerApplication` in your `HttpServer` class. After all, you want multiple servers, not applications.

In my simplest test, the following works:

```
#include <Poco/Net/HTMLForm.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPRequestHandler.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPRequestHandlerFactory.h>
#include <Poco/Net/ServerSocket.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPServer.h>
#include <Poco/Util/ServerApplication.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPServerRequest.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPServerResponse.h>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

boost::asio::io_service service(100);

class RequestHandler : public Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler {
public:
    RequestHandler(){}
    void handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request, Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse& response){}
};

class RequestHandlerFactory : public Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandlerFactory {
public:
    RequestHandlerFactory(){}
    Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler* createRequestHandler(const Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request)
    {
        return new RequestHandler();
    }
};

class HttpServer : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<HttpServer>{

    Poco::Net::ServerSocket svs;
    Poco::Net::HTTPServer srv;

public:
    HttpServer(std::string address_, Poco::UInt16 port_):
        svs(Poco::Net::SocketAddress(address_.empty() ? "127.0.0.1" : address_, port_)),
        srv(new RequestHandlerFactory(), svs, new Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams)
    {
        svs.setReuseAddress(true);
        svs.setReusePort(true);
    }

    virtual ~HttpServer(){}

    void start()
    {
        service.post(
            boost::bind(&HttpServer::exec, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void stop()
    {
        srv.stop();
    }

private:
    void exec()
    {
        srv.start();
    }    
};
```

In `main`, I create a subclass of `ServerApplication` for the sole reason of claling the protected method `waitForTerminationRequest()` before exit of main. If you need argument parsing, of course pass `argc, argv` to `app.run`. But at this point I don't see the need.

```
int main() {
    struct App : Poco::Util::ServerApplication {
        ~App() {
            waitForTerminationRequest();
        }
    } app;

    for (int i=0; i<2; ++i) {
        boost::make_shared<HttpServer>("", 8080+i)->start();
    }
}
```

---

OLD ANSWER TEXT

How are you instantiating the `HttpServer` objects?

1. You should, obviously, use `boost::make_shared<HttpServer>(host, port)` (or `shared_ptr<HttpServer>(new HttpServer(host, port))`) for `enable_shared_from_this` to be allowed. Don't forget to hold on to the shared ptr at least until the service has been started (by posting it's `exec()` call to `io_service`).

   Specifically, this is illegal:

   ```
   for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
       HttpServer s("", 8080+i);
       s.start();
   }
   ```

   Instead, use e.g.

   ```
   for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
       boost::make_shared<HttpServer>("", 8080+i)->start();
   }
   ```
2. Also, if you're going to run it on a pool of 100 threads, you ***need*** to either use a `strand` (for a logical thread of execution) ***or*** lock the `HttpServer` object before you use it on any thread.

   - [Why do I need strand per connection when using boost::asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042)

Comment: Im instantiating without problems:
    boost::shared_ptr<HttpServer> server(new HttpServer("127.0.0.1", 8080));
Instantiation and lock are not the problems =/, thanks.

Comment: @lopes I don't doubt that you do. However, you don't show that code. So it's the first thing to check. (Please add it to the question instead of in comments)