# Ensure no new wait is accepted by boost::deadline_timer unless previous wait is expired

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I am trying to achieve synchronization operation for hardware devices controlled by my C++ code.

Suppose Two types of devices are there on which I can perform `Open/Close`.
What I need to achieve is Open one type of device for `Specified Duration`. Same is true for Second type Of device.

I have written code with `boost::deadline_timer`:

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>


class Test : public std::enable_shared_from_this <Test>
{
public:
    Test() :io_(), timerOne_(io_),timerTwo_(io_){}
    void Open(int num);
    void Close(int num);
    void TimedOpen(int num, int dur);
    void Run();
private:
    boost::asio::io_service io_;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timerOne_;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timerTwo_;
};

void Test::Open(int type)
{
    std::cout << "Open for Number : " << type << std::endl;
}

void Test::Close(int type)
{
    std::cout << "Close for Number : " << type << std::endl;
}

void Test::TimedOpen(int type, int dur)
{
    switch (type)
    {
    case 1:
    {
              io_.reset();
              auto fn = std::bind(&Test::Open, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1);
              fn(type);
              timerOne_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(dur));
              timerOne_.async_wait(std::bind(&Test::Close, shared_from_this(), type));
              Run();
              std::cout << "Function Exiting" << std::endl;
              std::cout << "-----------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
              return;
    }

    case 2:
    {
              io_.reset();
              auto fn = std::bind(&Test::Open, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1);
              fn(type);
              timerTwo_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(dur));
              timerTwo_.async_wait(std::bind(&Test::Close, shared_from_this(), type));
              Run();
              std::cout << "Function Exiting" << std::endl;
              std::cout << "-----------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
              return;
    }

    }

}

void Test::Run()
{
    boost::thread th(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_));
}

int main()
{
    auto t = std::make_shared<Test>();
    t->TimedOpen(1, 60);
    t->TimedOpen(2, 30);
    t->TimedOpen(1, 5);
    t->TimedOpen(2, 2);
    char line[128];
    while (std::cin.getline(line, 128))
    {
        if (strcmp(line, "\n")) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The Output is:

```
Open for Number : 1
Function Exiting
-----------------------------------------------
Open for Number : 2
Function Exiting
-----------------------------------------------
Open for Number : 1
Close for Number : 1
Function Exiting
-----------------------------------------------
Open for Number : 2
Close for Number : 2
Function Exiting
-----------------------------------------------
Close for Number : 2
Close for Number : 1
```

For `timerOne_` It does not wait for previous `wait` to expire i.e. as soon as `t->TimedOpen(1, 5)` is executed the previous action `t->TimedOpen(1, 60)` is cancelled.

So  `Close for Number : 1` appears in output without waiting for `t->TimedOpen(1, 60)`.

What I want to achieve is that if `multiple waits are encountered` for any type of `timer`, all the operations should be queued i.e.

If I type:

```
t->TimedOpen(1, 60);
t->TimedOpen(1, 10);
t->TimedOpen(1, 5);
```

It should do `TimedOpen Operation` for `60+10+5` seconds. Currently it does only for 5 secs. Also It should be non blocking i.e. I can not use `wait() instead of async_wait()`.

How do I achieve it?

**Summary:**
My requirement is to schedule operations on a `boost::deadline_timer()` i.e. multiple operations on it will be queued unless previous wait is expired.

Comment: IMHO a solution is to accumulate a timer duration (`dur`) in the `TimedOpen` method, store the time of the 1st  `TimedOpen` call and use the `basic_deadline_timer::expires_at` method with summary of the initial time and the duration summary instead of `basic_deadline_timer::expires_from_now`

Comment: @megabyte1024 accumulation won't give me .. scheduling functionality.. Suppose I want to ensure the sequential operation.. it can not ensure

Comment: Not clear.. Do I understand correctly that 3 calls of the dead_line timer handler are expected for the example with 3 calls of `TimeOpen`? If yes, then you need to build your own queue of operations, etc. The `expires_from_now` cancels any pending asynchronous waits. See the [help](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer.html).

Answer (score 1):

Like was mentioned in a comment, you will want to have queues per "type".

Let's name the per-type queue a "session".

By chaining all async waits from a single queue on a single `strand`¹ you get effective serialization (also avoids synchronization on the queue/session).

The only tricky bit is to start async wait when none is in flight. The invariant is that async operations are in flight iff `!queue_.empty()`:

```
struct Session : std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
    Session(boost::asio::io_service &io, int type) : strand_(io), timer_(io), type(type) {}

    void Enqueue(int duration) {
        auto This = shared_from_this();
        strand_.post([This,duration,this] { 
                std::cout << "t0 + " << std::setw(4) << mark() << "ms Enqueue for Number: "  << type <<  " (dur:"  << duration       <<  ")\n";
                This->queue_.push(duration);
                if (This->queue_.size() == 1)
                    This->Wait();
            });
    }

  private:
    boost::asio::strand strand_;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer_;
    int type;
    std::queue<int> queue_;

    void Close() {
        assert(!queue_.empty());
        std::cout << "t0 + " << std::setw(4) << mark() << "ms Close for Number :  "  << type <<  " (dur:"  << queue_.front() <<  ") (depth " << queue_.size() << ")\n";

        queue_.pop();
        Wait();
    }
    void Wait() {
        if (!queue_.empty()) {
            std::cout << "t0 + " << std::setw(4) << mark() << "ms Open for Number :   "  << type <<  " (dur:"  << queue_.front() <<  ") (depth " << queue_.size() << ")\n";
            timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(queue_.front()));
            timer_.async_wait(strand_.wrap(std::bind(&Session::Close, shared_from_this())));
        }
    }
};
```

Now the `Test` class becomes much simpler (in fact it doesn't need to be "shared" at all, but I've left that detail as the proverbial exercise for the reader):

```
class Test : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Test> {
    using guard = boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex>;
public:
    Test() : io_(), work_(boost::asio::io_service::work(io_)) {
        io_thread = boost::thread([this] { io_.run(); });
    }

    void TimedOpen(int num, int duration);

    void Stop() {
        {
            guard lk(mx_);
            if (work_) work_.reset();
        }
        io_thread.join();
    }

    ~Test() {
        Stop();

        guard lk(mx_);
        timers_ex_.clear();
    }

private:
    mutable boost::mutex mx_;
    boost::asio::io_service io_;
    boost::optional<boost::asio::io_service::work> work_;
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Session> > timers_ex_;
    boost::thread io_thread;
};

void Test::TimedOpen(int type, int duration) {
    guard lk(mx_);

    auto &session = timers_ex_[type];
    if (!session) session = std::make_shared<Session>(io_, type);

    session->Enqueue(duration);
}
```

As you can see I've

- extrapolated to any number of types
- made operations thread-safe
- added relative timestamps in milliseconds since `t0`
- fixed the completely broken `io_service` lifetime. Now, construction starts the service. The `work_` variable keeps it alive when idle.
- `Stop()` shuts it down (draining the session queues first).
- Destruction calls `Stop()` implicitly

Here's a test run:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b16f049b81e0fdc1)</kbd>**

```
int main() {
    auto t = std::make_shared<Test>();
    t->TimedOpen(1, 300);
    t->TimedOpen(2, 150);
    t->TimedOpen(1,  50);
    t->TimedOpen(2,  20);

    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(400));
    std::cout << "================\n";
    t->TimedOpen(1,  50);
    t->TimedOpen(2,  20);
    t->TimedOpen(1, 300);
    t->TimedOpen(2, 150);

    t->Stop();
}
```

Prints

```
t0 +    0ms Enqueue for Number: 1 (dur:300)
t0 +    0ms Open for Number :   1 (dur:300) (depth 1)
t0 +    0ms Enqueue for Number: 2 (dur:150)
t0 +    0ms Open for Number :   2 (dur:150) (depth 1)
t0 +    0ms Enqueue for Number: 1 (dur:50)
t0 +    0ms Enqueue for Number: 2 (dur:20)
t0 +  150ms Close for Number :  2 (dur:150) (depth 2)
t0 +  150ms Open for Number :   2 (dur:20) (depth 1)
t0 +  170ms Close for Number :  2 (dur:20) (depth 1)
t0 +  300ms Close for Number :  1 (dur:300) (depth 2)
t0 +  300ms Open for Number :   1 (dur:50) (depth 1)
t0 +  350ms Close for Number :  1 (dur:50) (depth 1)
================
t0 +  400ms Enqueue for Number: 1 (dur:50)
t0 +  400ms Open for Number :   1 (dur:50) (depth 1)
t0 +  400ms Enqueue for Number: 2 (dur:20)
t0 +  400ms Open for Number :   2 (dur:20) (depth 1)
t0 +  400ms Enqueue for Number: 1 (dur:300)
t0 +  400ms Enqueue for Number: 2 (dur:150)
t0 +  420ms Close for Number :  2 (dur:20) (depth 2)
t0 +  420ms Open for Number :   2 (dur:150) (depth 1)
t0 +  450ms Close for Number :  1 (dur:50) (depth 2)
t0 +  450ms Open for Number :   1 (dur:300) (depth 1)
t0 +  570ms Close for Number :  2 (dur:150) (depth 1)
t0 +  750ms Close for Number :  1 (dur:300) (depth 1)
```

---

¹ [Why do I need strand per connection when using boost::asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042)