# boost asio tcp async read/write

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

i have an understanding problem how boost asio handles this:

[image]

When I watch my request response on client side, I can use following boost example [Example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_client.cpp)

But I don't understand what happens if the server send every X ms some status information to the client. Have I open a serperate socket for this or can my client difference which is the request, response and the cycleMessage ?

Can it happen, that the client send a Request and read is as cycleMessage? Because he is also waiting for async_read because of this Message?

---

```
class TcpConnectionServer : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<TcpConnectionServer>
{
public:
    typedef  boost::shared_ptr<TcpConnectionServer> pointer;
    static pointer create(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    {
        return pointer(new TcpConnectionServer(io_service));
    }
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket()
    {
        return m_socket;
    }
    void Start()
    {
        SendCycleMessage();
        boost::asio::async_read(
                m_socket, boost::asio::buffer(m_data, m_dataSize),
                boost::bind(&TcpConnectionServer::handle_read_data, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

private:
    TcpConnectionServer(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
        : m_socket(io_service),m_cycleUpdateRate(io_service,boost::posix_time::seconds(1))
      {

      }
    void handle_read_data(const boost::system::error_code& error_code)
    {
        if (!error_code)
        {
        std::string answer=doSomeThingWithData(m_data);
        writeImpl(answer);

        boost::asio::async_read(
                m_socket, boost::asio::buffer(m_data, m_dataSize),
                boost::bind(&TcpConnectionServer::handle_read_data, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else
        {

            std::cout << error_code.message() << "ERROR DELETE READ \n";
            // delete this;
        }
    }


    void SendCycleMessage()
    {
        std::string data = "some usefull data";
        writeImpl(data);
        m_cycleUpdateRate.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
        m_cycleUpdateRate.async_wait(boost::bind(&TcpConnectionServer::SendTracedParameter,this));
    }

    void writeImpl(const std::string& message)
    {
        m_messageOutputQueue.push_back(message);
        if (m_messageOutputQueue.size() > 1)
        {
            // outstanding async_write
            return;
        }

        this->write();
    }

    void write()
    {
        m_message = m_messageOutputQueue[0];
        boost::asio::async_write(
                m_socket,
                boost::asio::buffer(m_message),
                boost::bind(&TcpConnectionServer::writeHandler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

    void writeHandler(const boost::system::error_code& error, const size_t bytesTransferred)
    {
        m_messageOutputQueue.pop_front();
        if (error)
        {
            std::cerr << "could not write: " << boost::system::system_error(error).what() << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        if (!m_messageOutputQueue.empty())
        {
            // more messages to send
            this->write();
        }
    }

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket m_socket;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer m_cycleUpdateRate;
    std::string m_message;

    const size_t m_sizeOfHeader = 5;
    boost::array<char, 5> m_headerData;
    std::vector<char> m_bodyData;

    std::deque<std::string> m_messageOutputQueue;
};
```

With this implementation I will not need boost::asio::strand or? Because I will not modify the m_messageOutputQueue from an other thread.

But when I have on my client side an m_messageOutputQueue which i can access from an other thread on this point I will need strand? Because then i need the synchronization? Did I understand something wrong?

Comment: What is the cycleMessage you refer to?

Comment: The cycleMessage is the message from the server to the client. It could be for e.g. timestamp and will be send every X ms

Answer (score 2):

The differentiation of the message is part of your application protocol.

ASIO merely provides transport.

Now, indeed if you want to have a "keepalive" message you will have to *design* your protocol in such away that the client can distinguish the messages.

The trick is to think of it at a higher level. Don't deal with `async_read` on the client directly. Instead, make `async_read` put messages on a queue (or several queues; the status messages could not even go in a queue but supersede a previous non-handled status update, e.g.).

Then code your client against those queues.

A simple thing that is typically done is to introduce message framing and a message type id:

```
FRAME offset 0: message length(N)
FRAME offset 4: message data
FRAME offset 4+N: message checksum
FRAME offset 4+N+sizeof checksum: sentinel (e.g. 0x00, or a larger unique signature)
```

The structure there makes the protocol more extensible. It's easy to add encryption/compression without touch all other code. There's built-in error detection etc.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. One Question which is not clear to me: is it not possible that my client do async_write as request and the client async_read gets it? Is it always save that just the server read and write of the client? What happens if my client and my server write on the same time?

Comment: No that won't happen. Stream sockets are a full duplex channel. What you write on one end comes out (only) on the other end

Comment: The client and server have different sockets anyway (assuming you're not actually writing both in the same process...). Inside the same process you need to synchronize operations on a single socket.

Comment: I assume that inside one instance of io_service.run() i don't have to synchronize or? I tried on my client side an async_read which read all the time my socket and i have a sendMessage method which write data to the socket when i get a user input. I thought that boost asio makes the synchronization?

Comment: What do you mean "inside run()"? That's library internal. If you mean, "only one thread running `io_service::run()` then, yes, you have what is known as [an **implicit strand**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042

Comment: My Problem was that I misunderstand, I edited my post above to make it clear. But i Think i understand it now thank you