# Boost: is it safe to use multiple recursion in async calls?

Tags: c++, recursion, boost-asio

I'm pretty new in asio framework, so please be kind.
I've investigated several boost asio example and found that people use async call like this:

```
void read()
{
    async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(&user_[0], user_.size()),
       boost::bind(&Connection::handle_user_read, this,
       placeholders::error, placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
void handle_user_read(...)
{
    ...
    read();
    ...
}
```

I think this code is not safe because it uses multiple recursion.
So it cant be used when a lot of read operations are performed because of call stack overflow.
I'm not 100% sure in this and unable to find any similar thoughts from other people.

Could anyone please explain this in details?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose the read() function just adds new async read request to the I/O queue and exits immediately, so there's no recursion in this code.

I mean, the read() doesn't call Connection::handle_user_read directly. It just *store* the function pointer inside the IO queue. This function is going to be invoked asynchronously by external code when some new chunk of data will be available.

Comment: So : yes it's safe. that's the way they do it in the boost documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I did not thought about that. Now it's perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's not recursion, it's chained async operations; be aware of threading issues:

[Why do I need strand per connection when using boost::asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042)