# Boost.Asio - how to check that all intermediate handlers performed in a strand?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, ssl, boost

I have client-server app that uses Boost.Asio and SSL. Server has many threads. Server uses `async_read` and sometimes I get invoked async handler with `bytes_received != bytes_expected` and `ec == 0`. Most of the time app misses 1-500 bytes out of 2048-16384 bytes (usual size of logical packets in the app).

My issue similar to this one - [Why boost::asio::async_read completion sometimes executed with bytes_transferred=0 and ec=0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419969).

To fix it I made dedicated `io_service::strand` for each `ssl::stream`
 and one `io_service::strand` for `ssl::context` (which is shared among threads). I wrapped all async invocations with `io_service::strand::wrap()` (async_read, async_write, async_wait). Routine launched via `io_service::strand::post()`. I made debug checks before each invocation of socket method (`io_service::strand::running_in_this_thread()`). But I still have broken packets...

Due to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12801042/1802974 during the processing of `async_read`/`async_write` Boost.Asio can make `intermediate handlers` which must be inside the strand. This is the last chance to fix this weird issue. How can I check that all `intermediate handlers` actually performed inside dedicated socket strand?

**UPDATE**

After a lot of debugging I found my issue - it is not connected to SSL at all. That was because of wrong manipulation of buffers...

In my app I use `std::vector<char>` as a buffer (two vectors for each socket - one for read operations and one for write operations). Vectors created right after socket opened with default (zero) length.

I have a binary protocol. Each packet consists of a header and payload. Header contains length of payload. After server received header of a packet it checks that read buffer is sufficient to receive payload. If buffer is smaller than packet payload - server increases the buffer.

Code that was used to manage buffer size (do not do this ever):

```
if (buf.capacity() >= newSize)
{
    return;
}
buf.resize(newSize);
```

After that I constructed asio buffer like this:

```
boost::asio::buffer(myVector, expectedPacketLength)
```

I.e. this overload was used: [boost.org](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer/overload24.html)

Now we will see the error:

```
- Client sends packet of the length 400
- Server increases size of the buffer to 400 (size == 400, capacity == 400)
- Server successfully receives packet
- Client sends packet of the length 415
- Server increases size of the buffer to 415.
  But `std::vector` has its own logic to increase capacity and reallocate data.
  After 'resizing' actual parameters - capacity == 800, size == 415.
- Server successfully receives packet
- Client sends packet of the length 430
- Server try to increase size of a buffer, but capacity is already bigger than 430.
  Nothing is done.
- Server creates buffer.
  But mentioned overload of `boost::asio::buffer` has its own logic - size of created buffer 415.
- voila, we miss 15 last bytes of the packet
```

Why I post it here?

Be carefull with the buffers )) Just use `std::vector::reserve` to increase size and use most basic overload of `boost::asio::buffer` [boost.org](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer/overload5.html)

Comment: Can you provide a Could a minimal example reproducing the issue described in the first paragraph ? Maybe using `strand` is not the _fix_ that it needs.

Comment: You could wrap the handlers in a custom functor that logs/checks the strand identity. However, you could also show us how you wrap the async operations in the strand for review.