# Do I need to implement blocking when using boost::asio?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

My question is, if I run io_service::run () on multiple threads, do I need to implement blocking on these asynchronous functions?

example:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

void test_timer(boost::system::error_code ec)
{
    //I need to lock up here ?
    if (i++ == 10)
    {
        j = i * 10;
    }
    timer.expires_at(timer.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));
    timer.async_wait(&test_timer);
}

void threadMain()
{
    io_service.run();
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread_group workers;
    timer.async_wait(&test_timer);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        workers.create_thread(&threadMain);
    }

    io_service.run();
    workers.join_all();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `asio` is not necessarily meant to be used with threads.

Comment: What do you mean _"blocking"_? Using synchronizaiton mechanisms?

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar well, something has to execute code:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of async is that it is non-blocking.

If you mean to ask "do I have to synchronize access to shared objects from different threads" - that question is unrelated and the answer depends on the thread-safety documented for the object you are sharing.

For Asio, basically (rough summary) you need to synchronize concurrent access (concurrent as in: from multiple threads) to *all types* except `boost::asio::io_context`¹,².

### Your Sample

Your sample uses multiple threads running the io service, meaning handlers run on any of those threads. This means that effectively you're sharing the globals and indeed they need protection.

***However*** Because your application logic (the async call chain) dictates that only one operation is ever pending, and the next async operation on the shared timer object is *always* scheduled from within that chain, the access is *logically* all from a single thread (called an *implicit strand*. See [Why do I need strand per connection when using boost::asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The simplest thing that would work:

### Logical Strand

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79326df49120c1f3)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer { io_service };

struct state_t {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
} state;

void test_timer(boost::system::error_code ec)
{
    if (ec != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
        {
            if (state.i++ == 10) {
                state.j = state.i * 10;
                if (state.j > 100)
                    return; // stop after 5 seconds
            }
        }
        timer.expires_at(timer.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(50));
        timer.async_wait(&test_timer);
    }
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread_group workers;
    timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(50));
    timer.async_wait(&test_timer);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        workers.create_thread([] { io_service.run(); });
    }

    workers.join_all();
    std::cout << "i = " << state.i << std::endl;
    std::cout << "j = " << state.j << std::endl;
}
```

> **Note** I removed the `io_service::run()` from the main thread as it is redundant with the `join()` (unless you really wanted ***6*** threads running the handlers, not 5).

Prints

```
i = 11
j = 110
```

### Caveat

There's a pitfall lurking here. Say, you didn't want to bail at a fixed number, like I did, but want to stop, you'd be tempted to do:

```
timer.cancel();
```

from `main`. That's **not** legal, because the `deadline_timer` object is *not* thread safe. You'd need to either

- use a global `atomic_bool` to signal the request for termination
- post the `timer.cancel()` on the same *strand* as the timer async chain. However, there is only an explicit strand, so you can't do it without changing the code to use an explicit strand.

### More Timers

Let's complicate things by having two timers, with their own implicit strands. This means access to the timer instances still need not be synchronized, but access to `i` and `j` **does** need to be.

> **Note** In this demo I use `synchronized_value<>` for elegance. You can write similar logic manually using `mutex` and `lock_guard`.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/901e7cbf57691c52)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/synchronized_value.hpp>
#include <iostream>

boost::asio::io_service io_service;

struct state {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
};

boost::synchronized_value<state> shared_state;

struct TimerChain {
    boost::asio::deadline_timer _timer;

    TimerChain() : _timer{io_service} {
        _timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(50));
        resume();
    }

    void resume() {
        _timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&TimerChain::test_timer, this, _1));
    };

    void test_timer(boost::system::error_code ec)
    {
        if (ec != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
            {
                auto state = shared_state.synchronize();
                if (state->i++ == 10) {
                    state->j = state->i * 10;
                }
                if (state->j > 100) return; // stop after some iterations
            }
            _timer.expires_at(_timer.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(50));
            resume();
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    boost::thread_group workers;
    TimerChain timer1;
    TimerChain timer2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        workers.create_thread([] { io_service.run(); });
    }

    workers.join_all();
    auto state = shared_state.synchronize();
    std::cout << "i = " << state->i << std::endl;
    std::cout << "j = " << state->j << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
i = 12
j = 110
```

### Adding The Explicit Strands

Now it's pretty straight-forward to add them:

```
struct TimerChain {
    boost::asio::io_service::strand _strand;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer _timer;

    TimerChain() : _strand{io_service}, _timer{io_service} {
        _timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(50));
        resume();
    }

    void resume() {
        _timer.async_wait(_strand.wrap(boost::bind(&TimerChain::test_timer, this, _1)));
    };

    void stop() { // thread safe
        _strand.post([this] { _timer.cancel(); });
    }

    // ...
```

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbbfa1566af5143e)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/synchronized_value.hpp>
#include <iostream>

boost::asio::io_service io_service;

struct state {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
};

boost::synchronized_value<state> shared_state;

struct TimerChain {
    boost::asio::io_service::strand _strand;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer _timer;

    TimerChain() : _strand{io_service}, _timer{io_service} {
        _timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(50));
        resume();
    }

    void resume() {
        _timer.async_wait(_strand.wrap(boost::bind(&TimerChain::test_timer, this, _1)));
    };

    void stop() { // thread safe
        _strand.post([this] { _timer.cancel(); });
    }

    void test_timer(boost::system::error_code ec)
    {
        if (ec != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
            {
                auto state = shared_state.synchronize();
                if (state->i++ == 10) {
                    state->j = state->i * 10;
                }
            }
            // continue indefinitely
            _timer.expires_at(_timer.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(50));
            resume();
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    boost::thread_group workers;
    TimerChain timer1;
    TimerChain timer2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        workers.create_thread([] { io_service.run(); });
    }

    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(10));
    timer1.stop();
    timer2.stop();

    workers.join_all();

    auto state = shared_state.synchronize();
    std::cout << "i = " << state->i << std::endl;
    std::cout << "j = " << state->j << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
i = 400
j = 110
```

---

¹ (or using the legacy name `boost::asio::io_service`)

² lifetime mutations are not considered member operations in this respect (you have to manually synchronize construction/destruction of shared objects even for thread-safe objects)