# I want to know some boost::asio's mechanism

Tags: c++, boost, asio

I am using `boost::asio` to make server. But I want to know asio's mechanism. Let's start with some pseudo-code:

#### Pseudo Code (server)

```
async_read_some(MY::read1);

MY::read1() {
    async_read_some(MY::read1);
    async_write(someData);  // someData : "ABCD"
}
```

#### Scenario

- client:

  1. send data to server.
  2. send data to server.( not yet recv data ).
  3. recv data from server.

  Now I worry that received data is mixed from server.

  - expected : "ABCD" "ABCD"
  - wrong: "AABBCDCD"

#### Question

I know that `async_write` function is guaranteed to be in order.

Thus, are the contents of the packets mixed?

#### Update:

Is this right?

```
async_read_some(MY::read1);

MY::read1() {
    async_write(someData, MY::write1);  // someData : "ABCD"
}

MY::write1() {
    async_read_some(MY::read1);
}
```

Comment: You need to wait for the handler to be called before you call write async again. Eg. you are not supposed to do two write async in a row before the first one completes. Same with read. But you can do both read and write at the same time.

Comment: I am not understand your comment well. I added psuedo code. It must write above skeleton? Could you write example about wrong/right asio code?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042