# Synchronize access to boost async_write

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm using a `C` library which rips PDF data and provides me with that data via callbacks. Two callbacks are used, one which provides me with the job header and another which provides me with the the ripped data ranging from 1 - 50MB chunks.

I'm then taking that data and sending it across the wire via `TCP` to someone who cares.

I'm using the boost `async_write` to send that data across the wire. I want to synchronize access to the `async_write` until it's done sending the previous chunk of data.

The `C` callback functions:

```
void __stdcall HeaderCallback( void* data, int count )
{
    // The Send function is a member of my AsyncTcpClient class.
    // This is how I'm currently providing my API with the PDF data.
    client.Send( data, count );
}

void __stdcall DataCallback( void* data, int count )
{
    client.Send( data, count );
}
```

I receive the provided data in my `AsyncTcpClient` class's `Send` method.

```
void AsyncTcpClient::Send( void* buffer, size_t length )
    {
        // Write to the remote server.
        boost::asio::async_write( _session->socket,
            boost::asio::buffer( ( const char* )buffer, length ),
            [ this ]( boost::system::error_code const& error, std::size_t bytesTransfered )
        {
            if ( error )
            {
                _session->errorCode = error;
                OnRequestComplete( _session );
                return;
            }
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> cancelLock( _session->cancelGuard );
            if ( _session->cancelled )
            {
                OnRequestComplete( _session );
                return;
            }               
        } );
    }
```

How can I synchronize access to the `async_write` function? 
Using a `mutex` at the start of the `Send` function would be pointless as the `async_write` returns immediately.
It's also pointless to store the `mutex` in a `unique_lock` member variable and attempt to unlock it in the `async_write` callback lambda as that'll blow up.

How can I synchronize access to the `async_write` function without using `strand`?
The first iteration of the program wont use `strand` for synchronization, I will be implementing that later.

Comment: buffer the data and call async_write if there's not already one active. in async_write's handler, check if there's more buffered data and call async_write again if there is. If there is more than one thread involved, you will need to add some synchronisation.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an [io_context::strand](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context__strand.html).

[One example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/server3/connection.cpp) from many others, but [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042) will help you.

Comment: Yeah, I did end up using a `strand`.