# Access member variable in one thread only, but not the thread of the class instance

Tags: multithreading, c++11, networking, boost-asio

I am facing the following problem:

I have a `RpcExecutor` class. This class:

1. sends rpc requests
2. receives rpc responses

I keep everything asynchronous (through boost.asio). Every time a request is sent, a write handler will be invoked that modifies a map:

```
async_write(...., [this, ...](error_code ec, size_t bytesTransferred) {
                    //
                    pendingRequests_.insert(requestId, move(myPromise));
           };
```

I start to listen in the same socket, with `async_read_until`, and replies come, possibly out of order. I also need to modify `pendingRequests_` from this hanlder:

```
async_read(... [this, ...](error_code ec, size_t bytesTransferred) {
                  ...
                  pendingRequests_.at(requestId).set_value(...);
                  pendingRequests_.erase(requestId);
});
```

My class looks like this:

```
class RpcExecutor {
private:
      std::unique_ptr<std::map<std::uint64_t, MyPromise>> pendingRequests_;
      ...
};
```

In order to make sure that the initialization of `pendingRequests_`, the reading and the writing of `pendingRequests_` are done through the same thread (I did check it is the case), I have the following restrictions applied:

1. there is a single `asio::run()` thread running, which is a different thread from `RpcExecutor` instance.
2. I initialize the `pendingRequests_` pointed-to object inside a `boost::asio::post(myIoContext, ...)`, meaning that it is initialized in the same thread where `asio::run` is executed.
3. The `async_read` handler and `async_write` handler are executed in the same thread as `io_context::run`, which is the same thread as `boost::asio::post`.

All in all:

- `boost::asio::post`, `async_read` handler and `async_write` handler are executed in the same thread.
- `RpcExecutor` class instance is created in another thread.

### Result

- `async_read` and `async_write` handler do not see the same memory address for `pendingRequests_`.

### Questions

1. How should I initialize a `map` that I can use from my handlers thread taking into account that `RpcExecutor` class instance is in another thread? Even if I initialize the pointed-to element in the same thread as `asio::context::run` via `post`, the handlers still see different addresses for the object.
2. Do I need mutexes of any kind? I want, actually, to do all reads/writes from a single thread, even if not the same thread as `RpcExecutor` class instance, which holds the `pendingTasks_`member variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042 would be helpful

Comment: Thanks. It is indeed a different case and I have no idea how to fix it yet after reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was very subtle:

I was doing this at some line of my code:

```
executor_ = RpcExecutor(socket_);
```

The `RpcExecutor` was then created, started to listen for incoming messages, all in the constructor. But that object was moved to `executor_` variable after that.

Since my `async_read` and `async_read` handlers were capturing `this` and `this` was not the same address after the move, then they were showing different addresses:

- the incoming messages read was showing the original object `this`.
- the outgoing messages were showing the already-moved `this` address.

### Solution

1. Make the `RpcExecutor` non-copyable and non-movable for safety.
2. I also thought it was a good idea to call `RpcExecutor::listenIncomingMessage` explicitly.