# How thread-safe is boost::asio?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, asio

I have an io_context that is run by multiple threads. I'm using sockets and timers. I know that I need to wrap all async_writes by a strand to prevent concurrent writes to the socket.

But can two threads concurrently access the socket to issue an async_read and an async_write at the same time?

Or what about shutdown() or close() being called while another thread calls async_read? Or cancel() on a timer?

Do I need to protect the socket/timer with a mutex or strand in this cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has oft been asked and answered:

> ### [Thread Safety](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html#boost_asio.overview.core.threads.thread_safety)
>
> In general, it is safe to make concurrent use of distinct objects, but
>   unsafe to make concurrent use of a single object. However, types such
>   as io_context provide a stronger guarantee that it is safe to use a
>   single object concurrently.

So yes, you need to protect active accesses to you timer/socket objects. However, having asynchronous operations in flight is not a concern: it's about **your** accesses that require your synchronization.

So,

```
 asio::post(strand, [&sock] { sock.shutdown();});
```

is always safe, and when you have only 1 thread running the service, then

```
post(io_context_, [&sock] { sock.shutdown();});
```

is also fine. Both will have the effect of safely canceling any asynchronous operations still in flight on `sock`.

See also the excellent: [Why do I need strand per connection when using boost::asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042)

Comment: more idiomatic these days: `post(bind_executor(strand_, [&sock]{ .. }));`

Comment: @RichardHodges Agreed. Wait, can you use the `asio::post` free function with a single argument... TIL

Comment: Yes if you don’t bind the executor you get given a system_executor, which is probably not one of asio’s better ideas.