# How to pass a boost asio tcp socket to a thread for sending heartbeat to client or server

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I am writing a client/server program in boost TCP in which I want to send a HEARTBEAT message to the client every 2 seconds for which I am trying to create a new thread by which I can send it easily but unable to solve it. I am creating thread using `boost::thread t(hearbeatSender,sock);` this. but giving lots of errors. I also use bind to bind function name with the socket but not resolved the error.

```
void process(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket & sock);
std::string read_data(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket & sock);
void write_data(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket & sock,std::string);
void hearbeatSender(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket & sock);
int main()
{

    unsigned short port_num = 3333;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::any(), port_num);
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    try
    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io, ep.protocol());
        acceptor.bind(ep);
        acceptor.listen();
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(io);
        acceptor.accept(sock);
        boost::thread t(hearbeatSender,sock); 
        process(sock);
        t.join();

    }
    catch (boost::system::system_error &e)
    {
        std::cout << "Error occured! Error code = " << e.code()
        << ". Message: " << e.what();

        return e.code().value();
    }
  return 0;

}
void process(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket & sock)
{
    while(1){
    std::string data = read_data(sock);
    std::cout<<"Client's request is: "<<data<<std::endl;
    write_data(sock,data);
    }
}
std::string read_data(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket & sock)
{
    boost::asio::streambuf buf;
    boost::asio::read_until(sock, buf, "\n");
    std::string data = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(buf.data());
    return data;
}
void write_data(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket & sock,std::string data)
{
    boost::system::error_code error;
    std::string msg;
    int ch = data[0]-'0';
    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1: msg = "Case 1\n"; break;
        case 2: msg = "Case 2\n"; break;
        case 3: msg = "Case 3\n"; break;
        case 4: msg = "Case 4\n"; break;
        default: msg  = "Case default\n"; break;
    }
    boost::asio::write( sock, boost::asio::buffer(msg+ "\n"), error );
     if( !error ) {
        std::cout << "Server sent hello message!" << std::endl;
     }
     else {
        std::cout << "send failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
     }
}
void hearbeatSender(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket & sock)
{
    boost::system::error_code error;
    std::string msg = "HEARTBEAT";
    while(1)
    {
        sleep(2);
        std::cout<<msg<<std::endl;
        boost::asio::write( sock, boost::asio::buffer(msg+ "\n"), error );
        if( !error ) {
        std::cout << "Server sent HEARTBEAT message!" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "send failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a server-side code for responding to the message of the client and sending heartbeat to the client. This is a synchronous TCP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
try
    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io, ep.protocol());
        acceptor.bind(ep);
        acceptor.listen();
        auto sock = acceptor.accept();
        std::thread t([&sock]() {
            hearbeatSender(sock);
        });
        process(sock);
        t.join();

    }
```

Use it:

```
try{
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io, ep.protocol());
        acceptor.bind(ep);
        acceptor.listen();
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(io);
        acceptor.accept(sock);

        std::thread t([&sock]() {
            hearbeatSender(sock);
        });
        process(sock);
        t.join();
}
```

and also include header files:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
```

(Optional) you can also use `this_thread::sleep_for` instead of  `sleep()`
`std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));`

The problem of passing a socket to the thread is solved.

Now, for conversing a HEARTBEAT between a client and a server. Complete code can be checked from here:

[Client code HEARTBEAT transfer in every 5 seconds](https://github.com/sachinsaini4278/Socket-Programming-using-boost-asio/blob/master/SynClientHeartbeat.cpp)

[Server code for giving response to the client](https://github.com/sachinsaini4278/Socket-Programming-using-boost-asio/blob/master/SynServerHeartbeat.cpp)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(io);
    acceptor.accept(sock);
    boost::thread t(hearbeatSender,sock);
```

this:

```
    auto sock = acceptor.accept();
    std::thread t([&sock]() {
        hearbeatSender(sock);
    });
```

And instead of `sleep`, just used std::this_thread::sleep for compiling universally.

Here's the complete program that compiles and runs

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>


void process(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& sock);
std::string read_data(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& sock);
void write_data(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& sock, std::string);
void hearbeatSender(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& sock);
int main()
{

    unsigned short port_num = 3333;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::any(), port_num);
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    try
    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io, ep.protocol());
        acceptor.bind(ep);
        acceptor.listen();
        auto sock = acceptor.accept();
        std::thread t([&sock]() {
            hearbeatSender(sock);
        });
        process(sock);
        t.join();

    }
    catch (boost::system::system_error& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Error occured! Error code = " << e.code()
            << ". Message: " << e.what();

        return e.code().value();
    }
    return 0;

}
void process(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& sock)
{
    while (1) {
        std::string data = read_data(sock);
        std::cout << "Client's request is: " << data << std::endl;
        write_data(sock, data);
    }
}
std::string read_data(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& sock)
{
    boost::asio::streambuf buf;
    boost::asio::read_until(sock, buf, "\n");
    std::string data = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(buf.data());
    return data;
}
void write_data(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& sock, std::string data)
{
    boost::system::error_code error;
    std::string msg;
    int ch = data[0] - '0';
    switch (ch)
    {
    case 1: msg = "Case 1\n"; break;
    case 2: msg = "Case 2\n"; break;
    case 3: msg = "Case 3\n"; break;
    case 4: msg = "Case 4\n"; break;
    default: msg = "Case default\n"; break;
    }
    boost::asio::write(sock, boost::asio::buffer(msg + "\n"), error);
    if (!error) {
        std::cout << "Server sent hello message!" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "send failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
}
void hearbeatSender(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& sock)
{
    boost::system::error_code error;
    std::string msg = "HEARTBEAT";
    while (1)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
        std::cout << msg << std::endl;
        boost::asio::write(sock, boost::asio::buffer(msg + "\n"), error);
        if (!error) {
            std::cout << "Server sent HEARTBEAT message!" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "send failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It helps with the compiler message, but doesn't help with the data race and arguably threading anti patterns

Comment: Sure, but that's not what the OP was inquiring about.

Comment: Although, your answer is very thorough.

Comment: Did you compile the code? 
I compiled the code but it is giving me lots of errors. some I reloved but many errors still occurring. How to solve them? 
 error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::accept()’
         auto sock = acceptor.accept();

 note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
server.cpp:21:37: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
         auto sock = acceptor.accept();

Comment: If you find any solution for these error then please update.

Comment: I'm using boost 1.73.0.  What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using boost 1.65.1

Answer (score 1):

It's more than a little weird to use a heartbeat... "sender" thread with async IO.

What's more, there is no synchronization on the socket object, so that's a [data race](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model) which is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Finally, this is unsafe:

```
    std::string data = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(buf.data());
```

It assumes that the data() will be NUL-terminated (which isn't true).

### Typical, Single Threaded ASIO

You would not spawn threads for timers, but use e.g. `boost::asio::deadline_timer` or `boost::asio::highresolution_timer`. It can wait asynchronously, so you can do other tasks on the IO service until it expires.

Similarly you can do the request/response reading/writing asynchronously. The only "complicating" factor is that asynchronous calls don't complete before returning, so you have to make sure the buffers live long enough (they should not be a local variable).

Now, you already have a logical "unit" of lifetime that practically JUMPS out of the code at you:

[image]

That just screams to be rewritten as

```
struct LifeTimeUnit {
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock;

    void process();
    std::string read_data();
    void write_data(std::string);
    void hearbeatSender(sock);
};
```

Of course `LifeTimeUnit` is a funny name, so let's think of a better one: `Session` seems meaningful!

---

Now that we have a unit of lifetime, it can handsomely contain other things like buffers and the timer:

```
struct Session {
    Session(tcp::socket&& s) : sock(std::move(s)) {}

    void start() {
        hb_wait();
        req_loop();
    }

    void cancel() {
        hbtimer.cancel();
        sock.cancel(); // or shutdown() e.g.
    }

  private:
    bool checked(error_code ec, std::string const& msg = "error") {
        if (ec) {
            std::clog << msg << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
            cancel();
        }
        return !ec.failed();;
    }

    void req_loop(error_code ec = {}) {
        if (!checked(ec, "req_loop")) {
            async_read_until(sock, buf, "\n",
                    [this](error_code ec, size_t xfr) { on_request(ec, xfr); });
        }
    }

    void on_request(error_code ec, size_t n) {
        if (checked(ec, "on_request")) {
            request.resize(n);
            buf.sgetn(request.data(), n);

            response = "Case " + std::to_string(request.at(0) - '0') + "\n";
            async_write(sock, buffer(response), 
                    [this](error_code ec, size_t) { req_loop(ec); });
        }
    }

    void hb_wait(error_code ec = {}) {
        if (checked(ec, "hb_wait")) {
            hbtimer.expires_from_now(2s);
            hbtimer.async_wait([this](error_code ec) { hb_send(ec); });
        }
    }

    void hb_send(error_code ec) {
        if (checked(ec, "hb_send")) {
            async_write(sock, buffer(hbmsg), [this](error_code ec, size_t) { hb_wait(ec); });
        }
    }

    tcp::socket sock;
    boost::asio::high_resolution_timer hbtimer { sock.get_executor() };
    const std::string hbmsg = "HEARTBEAT\n";
    boost::asio::streambuf buf;
    std::string request, response;
};
```

The only public things are `start()` (actually we don't have a need for `cancel()` for now, but you know).

The main program can be much un-altered:

```
tcp::acceptor acceptor(io, tcp::v4());
acceptor.bind({{}, 3333});
acceptor.listen();

tcp::socket sock(io);
acceptor.accept(sock);

Session sess(std::move(sock));
sess.start(); // does both request loop and the heartbeat

io.run();
```

No more threads, perfect asynchrony! Using `bash` and `netcat` to test:

```
while sleep 4; do printf "%d request\n" {1..10}; done | netcat localhost 3333
```

Prints:

```
host 3333
HEARTBEAT
Case 1
Case 2
Case 3
Case 4
Case 5
Case 6
Case 7
Case 8
Case 9
Case 1
HEARTBEAT
HEARTBEAT
HEARTBEAT
Case 1
Case 2
Case 3
Case 4
Case 5
Case 6
Case 7
Case 8
Case 9
Case 1
^C
```

After stopping the client, the server exits with

```
on_request: End of file
hb_send: Operation canceled
```

### Single-Thread / Multi-Session

A big advantage is that now you can accept multiple clients on a single server thread. In fact, thousands of them concurrently without a problem.

```
int main() {
    boost::asio::thread_pool io(1);
    try {
        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io, tcp::v4());
        acceptor.bind({{}, 3333});
        acceptor.listen();

        std::list<Session> sessions;

        while (true) {
            tcp::socket sock(io);
            acceptor.accept(sock);

            auto& sess = sessions.emplace_back(std::move(sock));
            sess.start(); // does both request loop and the heartbeat

            sessions.remove_if([](Session& s) { return !s.is_active(); });
        }

        io.join();
    } catch (boost::system::system_error& e) {
        std::cout << "Error occured! Error code = " << e.code() << ". Message: " << e.code().message() << "\n";
        return e.code().value();
    }
}
```

Note how we subtly changed our execution-context to a singleton thread pool.
This means we still run all sessions on a single thread, but that's a different thread than running `main()`, meaning we can continue to accept connections.

To avoid ever-increasing `sessions` list, we weed out the inactive ones using a trivially implemented `is_active()` property.

> Note that we can ALMOST force a shutdown by doing
>
> ```
> for (auto& sess: sessions)
>     sess.cancel();
> ```
>
> That's ALMOST, because it requires posting the cancel operations on the pool thread:
>
> ```
> for (auto& sess: sessions)
>     post(io, [&sess] { sess.cancel(); });
> ```
>
> This is to avoid racing with any tasks on the IO pool

Since only the main thread ever touches `sessions` there is no need for locking.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7cdbba9eac688a6)**

Testing with

```
for a in 3 2 1; do (sleep $a; echo "$a request" | nc 127.0.0.1 3333)& done; time wait
```

Prints:

```
Case 1
Case 2
Case 3
HEARTBEAT
HEARTBEAT
...
```

### Multi-Threading For The Win?

Now we could add multi-threading. The changes are mild:

- we want to associate the socket with a strand (see [Why do I need strand per connection when using boost::asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042))
- note we already use `sock`'s executor to run the timer
- We have to take extra precautions to make all of the public interface in `Session` thread-safe:

  - post actions from `start()` and `cancel()` on the strand
  - make the `active` flag `atomic_bool`
- next up, we simply increase the number of threads in the pool from `1` to, say `10`

> Note, in practice it rarely makes sense to use more threads than logical cores. Also, in this simple example everything is IO bound, so a single thread probably already serves as well. This is just for demonstration

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3afd6dbf86ef79e3)**

```
boost::asio::thread_pool io(10);
try {
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io, tcp::v4());
    acceptor.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
    acceptor.bind({{}, 3333});
    acceptor.listen();

    std::list<Session> sessions;

    while (true) {

        tcp::socket sock(make_strand(io)); // NOTE STRAND!
// ...
// ...

    io.join();
```

And the changes in `Session`:

```
   void start() {
        active = true;
        post(sock.get_executor(), [this]{
            hb_wait();
            req_loop();
        });
    }

    void cancel() {
        post(sock.get_executor(), [this]{
            hbtimer.cancel();
            sock.cancel(); // or shutdown() e.g.
            active = false;
        });
    }

// ....

    std::atomic_bool active {false};
}
```

---