# I don't know why code using boost asio is causing an error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I created the main cpp file and three classes to create an asynchronous server.
`Server`, `Service`, and `Acceptor` respectively.
However, they caused errors in the build process, even though there were no errors in the visual studio 2019 environment.
I tried to fix the error, but most of the errors occurred in other files, so I couldn't even think of it myself.

`main`

```
#include "Server.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
#define DEFAULT_THREAD_SIZE 2;
using namespace boost;
int main()
{
 unsigned short port_num;
    std::cin >> port_num;
    try {
        Server srv;
        unsigned int threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() * 2;
        if (threads == 0) {
            threads = DEFAULT_THREAD_SIZE;
        }
        std::cout << "\nPort - " << port_num << "\nServer start\n";
        srv.Start(port_num, threads);
        while (1) {
            std::cin >> srv;
        }
    }
    catch (system::system_error& e) {
        std::cout << "\nError code: " << e.code() << "\nError Message\n" << e.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This includes Server.h, which defines Server class.

```
#include "Acceptor.h"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
using namespace boost;
class Server
{
public:
    Server();
    void Start(unsigned short port_num, unsigned int threads);
    void Stop();
    int Command(std::string& str);
private:
    asio::io_service mios;
    std::unique_ptr<asio::io_service::work> mWork;
    std::unique_ptr<Acceptor> mAcceptor;
    std::vector <std::unique_ptr<std::thread>> mThreads;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Server& srv);
```

Here's the implementation, Server.cpp.

```
#include "Server.h"
Server::Server() {
    mWork.reset(new asio::io_service::work(mios));
}
void Server::Start(unsigned short port_num, unsigned int threads) {
    assert(thread > 0);
    mAcceptor.reset(new Acceptor(mios, port_num));
    mAcceptor->Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        std::unique_ptr<std::thread> th(new std::thread([this]() {mios.run(); }));
        mThreads.push_back(std::move(th));
    }
}
void Server::Stop() {
    mAcceptor->Stop();
    mios.stop();

    for (auto& th : mThreads) {
        th->join();
    }
}
int Server::Command(std::string& str) {
    return 0;
}
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Server& srv) {
    std::string str;
    is >> str;
    srv.Command(str);
    return is;
}
```

This is Acceptor class.

```
#include "Service.h"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
using namespace boost;
class Acceptor
{
public:
    Acceptor(asio::io_service& ios, unsigned short port_num);
    void Start();
    void Stop();
private:
    std::shared_ptr<asio::io_service> mios;
    std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::acceptor> mAcceptor;
    std::atomic<bool> mIsStopped;
    void InitAccept();
    void OnAccept(const system::error_code ec, std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> sock);
};
```

```
#include "Acceptor.h"
Acceptor::Acceptor(asio::io_service& ios, unsigned short port_num) {
    mios = std::make_shared<asio::io_service>(ios);
    mAcceptor = std::make_shared<asio::ip::tcp::acceptor>(mios, asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(asio::ip::address_v4::any(), port_num));
    mIsStopped = false;
}
void Acceptor::Start() {
    mAcceptor->listen();
    InitAccept();
}
void Acceptor::Stop() {
    mIsStopped.store(true);
}

void Acceptor::InitAccept() {
    std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> sock(new asio::ip::tcp::socket(mios));
    mAcceptor->async_accept(*sock, [this, sock](const system::error_code& error) {OnAccept(error, sock);});
}
void Acceptor::OnAccept(const system::error_code ec, std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> sock) {
    if (ec.value() == 0 || ER) {
        (new Service(sock))->StartHandling();
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Error code:" << ec.value() << "error " << "Error message: " << ec.message() << "\n";
    }
    if (!mIsStopped.load()) {
        InitAccept();
    }
    else {
        mAcceptor->close();
    }
}
```

Service class

```
#define ER true
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
using namespace boost;
class Service
{
public:
    Service(std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> sock);
    void StartHandling();
private:
    void OnRequestReceived(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);
    std::string mReponse;
    std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> mSock;
    asio::streambuf mRequest;
    void OnReponseSent(const system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);

    void OnFinish();
    std::string ProcessRequest(asio::streambuf& request);
};
```

```
#include "Service.h"
Service::Service(std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> sock){
    mSock = sock;
}
void Service::StartHandling() {
    asio::async_read_until(mSock, mRequest, '\n', [this](const system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {OnRequestReceived(ec, bytes_transferred); });
}

void Service::OnRequestReceived(const system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    if (ec.value() != 0 || ER) {
        std::cout << "Error code:" << ec.value() << "Error message: " << ec.message() << "\n";
        OnFinish();
        return;
    }
    mReponse = ProcessRequest(mRequest);
    asio::async_write(mSock, asio::buffer(mReponse), [this](const system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {OnReponseSent(ec, bytes_transferred); });
}

void Service::OnReponseSent(const system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    if (ec.value() != 0 || ER) {
        std::cout << "Error code:" << ec.value() << "Error message: " << ec.message() << "\n";
    }
    OnFinish();
}

void Service::OnFinish() {
    delete this;
}
std::string Service::ProcessRequest(asio::streambuf& request) {
    std::string reponse;
    std::istream input(&request);
    std::getline(input, reponse);
    assert(reponse.back() == '\n');
    return reponse;
}
```

I have no idea what to do. I wanted to do it myself, but I couldn't even debug because I couldn't figure out where the problem was going and it wasn't built.

Comment: What are the errors?

Answer (score 5):

It simply doesn't compile. I genuinely wonder how people can come up with /so much/ code before noticing that stuff doesn't compile.

Rule #1: Baby Steps (this goes for the professionals just as much, only they have it internalized).

- You're doing stuff like:

  ```
  mios = std::make_shared<asio::io_service>(ios);
  ```

  This requires `io_service` to be copyable (which it isn't). You would probably make `mios` a reference:

  ```
  asio::io_service& mios;
  ```
- There seems to be a lot of "superstitious" use of shared_ptr all around.
- The fact that

  ```
  assert(thread > 0);
  ```

  misspelled `threads` indicates that you may have been building Release-only builds.
- Read the compiler messages:

  ```
  void Service::StartHandling() {
      asio::async_read_until(mSock, mRequest, '\n', [this](const system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {OnRequestReceived(ec, bytes_transferred); });
  }
  ```

  This triggers the error:

  ```
  /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_73_0/boost/asio/impl/read_until.hpp|959 col 53| error: no type named ‘executor_type’ in ‘class std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >’
  ```

  Obviously you meant `*mSock`. Same later:

  ```
  asio::async_write(*mSock, asio::buffer(mReponse), [this](const system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {OnReponseSent(ec, bytes_transferred); });
  ```

  > A pointer is *not* the object it points to - not even smart pointers. The point [sic] of smart pointers is not to make C++ equal to (say) Java - you should use Java if you wanted that.

With these it compiles: **[Live ON Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/R5FRmOCCLHVLSP6q)**

### More Review

- top-level const makes no difference in value arguments
- Don't use [`new` or `delete`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new):

  ```
   mWork.reset(new asio::io_service::work(mios));
  ```

  use `make_unique` instead

  ```
   mWork = std::make_unique<asio::io_service::work>(mios);
   // ...
   mAcceptor = std::make_unique<Acceptor>(mios, port_num);
  ```
- Use header guards (or `#pragma once`)
- Do not use namespace using-directives; use using-declarations instead
- Especially don't use namespace using-directives in header files (you make it
  impossible for your users to prevent/fix name collisions, which may lead to compile error **or** silent change of behaviour)
- Use constructor initializer lists (and move-semantics):

  ```
   Service::Service(std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> sock){
       mSock = sock;
   }
  ```

  Becomes

  ```
   Service::Service(std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> sock) 
       : mSock(std::move(sock))
   { }
  ```
- Here:

  ```
   (new Service(std::move(sock)))->StartHandling();
  ```

  Don't use new, don't superstitious-use shared pointer, and, ironically, in
  the case of `Service` consider using `enable_shared_from_this` so you **do**
  use `shared_ptr` instead of the `delete this;` anti-pattern.
- Initialize your primitive class members1

  ```
   std::atomic<bool> mIsStopped{};
  ```

  Without, it will have indeterminate value, which usually leads to UB when used
- Don't ignore errors:

  ```
   if (ec.value() == 0 || ER) {
       (new Service(std::move(sock)))->StartHandling();
   }
  ```

  Instead, report / log. Also, detect errors portably:

  ```
   if (!ec) {
  ```

  Or

  ```
   if (!ec.failed()) {
  ```
- generally, handle errors (`cin >> port_num` e.g.),
- catch by const&

> Intermediate result (still compiles): **[Live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/c4FYO92XdzAKcXWn)**

BONUS

- Simplify, use `asio::thread_pool`, uniform initalization
- USE `bytes_transferred`! read_until does **not** guarantee it stops on the
  delimiter, because that's not how TCP works. Trailing data can be present
  in the buffer. This means that in DEBUG builds this assert would sometimes fail:

  ```
   assert(request.back() == '\n');
  ```

  > Actually the code read `response.back()` which is guaranteed to fail because `getline` doesn't include it ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

  You might use `boost::iostreams::restrict` or instead
  `asio::dynamic_buffer()` on a `std::string` and pass a `string_view` into
  the handler (`ProcessRequest`):

  ```
   mReponse = ProcessRequest(std::string_view(mRequest).substr(0, bytes_transferred));
  ```

  And later

  ```
   #include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
   #include <boost/iostreams/stream_buffer.hpp>

   std::string Service::ProcessRequest(std::string_view request) {
       assert(request.back() == '\n');
       boost::iostreams::stream_buffer<boost::iostreams::array_source> buf(
           request.data(), request.size());

       std::istream input(&buf);
       std::string reponse;
       std::getline(input, reponse);
       return reponse;
   }
  ```
- Get rid of all the redundant shared pointers. If `Acceptor` is already
  dynamically allocated managed by a shared-pointer, there is really no need
  to *also* make it own its `tcp::acceptor` instance by shared_ptr. In general
  all the members could just be by value in your code. As long as the
  surrounding object stays around (as you do with Service) the members are
  guaranteed to stay alive as well.
- mIsStopped can be eliminated by simply `cancel()`-ing the acceptor instead. To get thread-safety, simply post to the relevant executor.
- If you wanted the server to actually exit when the stop command is executed, you need to make the `while(true)` loop have a stop condition, e.g.

  ```
   int Server::Command(std::string const& cmd) {
       std::cout << "Command: " << std::quoted(cmd) << "\n";
       if (cmd == "quit") {
           Stop();
           return 1;
       }
       std::cerr << "Unknown command (\"quit\" to exit)" << std::endl;
       return 0;
   }

   std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Server& srv) {
       std::string str;
       is >> str;
       if (srv.Command(str)) {
           is.setstate(std::ios::badbit);
       }
       return is;
   }
  ```

  And in `main`:

  ```
       while (std::cin >> srv) { }
  ```

### FULL DEMO:

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vq3oFBgqB9CpbQjD)**

- File `Acceptor.h`

  ```
   #ifndef _HOME_SEHE_PROJECTS_STACKOVERFLOW_ASIO_ACCEPTOR_H
   #define _HOME_SEHE_PROJECTS_STACKOVERFLOW_ASIO_ACCEPTOR_H

   #include "Service.h"
   class Acceptor {
     public:
       template <typename Executor>
       Acceptor(Executor ex, unsigned short port_num) : mAcceptor(make_strand(ex), {{}, port_num}) {}
       void Start();
       void Stop();

     private:
       tcp::acceptor mAcceptor;
       void InitAccept();
       void OnAccept(error_code ec, tcp::socket&& sock);
   };

   #endif
  ```
- File `Common.h`

  ```
   #pragma once
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <memory>
   #include <thread>
   #include <atomic>

   namespace asio = boost::asio;
   using boost::system::error_code;
   using asio::ip::tcp;
  ```
- File `Server.h`

  ```
   #ifndef _HOME_SEHE_PROJECTS_STACKOVERFLOW_ASIO_SERVER_H
   #define _HOME_SEHE_PROJECTS_STACKOVERFLOW_ASIO_SERVER_H

   #include "Acceptor.h"
   class Server {
     public:
       explicit Server(unsigned short port_num);
       void Start();
       void Stop();
       int Command(std::string const& str);

     private:
       asio::thread_pool mio;
       Acceptor mAcceptor;
   };

   std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Server& srv);

   #endif
  ```
- File `Service.h`

  ```
   #ifndef _HOME_SEHE_PROJECTS_STACKOVERFLOW_ASIO_SERVICE_H
   #define _HOME_SEHE_PROJECTS_STACKOVERFLOW_ASIO_SERVICE_H

   #include "Common.h"
   #include <iostream>
   class Service : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Service> {
     public:
       explicit Service(tcp::socket&& sock);
       void StartHandling();

     private:
       void OnRequestReceived(error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);
       std::string mRequest, mReponse;
       tcp::socket mSock;
       void OnReponseSent(error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred);

       std::string ProcessRequest(std::string_view request);
   };

   #endif
  ```
- File `Acceptor.cpp`

  ```
   #include "Acceptor.h"
   #include <utility>

   void Acceptor::Start() {
       mAcceptor.listen();
       InitAccept();
   }

   void Acceptor::Stop() {
       // be thread safe
       post(mAcceptor.get_executor(), [this] { mAcceptor.cancel(); });
   }

   void Acceptor::InitAccept() {
       mAcceptor.async_accept(
           make_strand(mAcceptor.get_executor()),
           [this](error_code error, tcp::socket&& sock) { OnAccept(error, std::move(sock)); });
   }

   void Acceptor::OnAccept(error_code ec, tcp::socket&& sock) {
       if (!ec.failed()) {
           std::make_shared<Service>(std::move(sock))->StartHandling();
           InitAccept();
       } else {
           std::cout << "OnAccept: " << ec.message() << "\n";
       }
   }
  ```
- File `main.cpp`

  ```
   #include "Server.h"
   #include <iostream>

   int main() {
       if (uint16_t port_num; std::cin >> port_num) {
           try {
               Server srv(port_num);
               std::cout << "Port - " << port_num << "\nServer start\n";
               srv.Start();

               while (std::cin >> srv) { }
           } catch (boost::system::system_error const& e) {
               std::cout << "Error " << e.code().message() << "\n";
           }
       } else {
           std::cerr << "Invalid input (port number required)\n";
       }
   }
  ```
- File `Server.cpp`

  ```
   #include "Server.h"
   #include <iomanip>

   Server::Server(unsigned short port_num)
       : mAcceptor(make_strand(mio), port_num) {}

   void Server::Start() { mAcceptor.Start(); }
   void Server::Stop() { mAcceptor.Stop(); }

   int Server::Command(std::string const& cmd) {
       std::cout << "Command: " << std::quoted(cmd) << "\n";
       if (cmd == "quit") {
           Stop();
           return 1;
       }
       std::cerr << "Unknown command (\"quit\" to exit)" << std::endl;
       return 0;
   }

   std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Server& srv) {
       std::string str;
       is >> str;
       if (srv.Command(str)) {
           is.setstate(std::ios::badbit);
       }
       return is;
   }
  ```
- File `Service.cpp`

  ```
   #include "Service.h"
   #include <utility>
   #include <iomanip>

   Service::Service(tcp::socket&& sock)
           : mSock(std::move(sock)) {}

   void Service::StartHandling() {
       asio::async_read_until(
           mSock, asio::dynamic_buffer(mRequest), '\n',
           [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
               OnRequestReceived(ec, bytes_transferred);
           });
   }

   void Service::OnRequestReceived(error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
       if (ec) {
           std::cout << "OnRequestReceived: " << ec.message() << "\n";
           return;
       }

       std::string_view view = mRequest;
       mReponse = ProcessRequest(view.substr(0, bytes_transferred));

       asio::async_write(
               mSock, asio::buffer(mReponse),
               [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
                   OnReponseSent(ec, bytes_transferred);
               });
   }

   void Service::OnReponseSent(error_code ec, std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
       if (ec) {
           std::cout << "OnReponseSent: " << ec.message() << "\n";
       }
   }

   #include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
   #include <boost/iostreams/stream_buffer.hpp>

   std::string Service::ProcessRequest(std::string_view request) {
       //std::cerr << "TRACE: " << std::quoted(request) << "\n";
       assert(request.back() == '\n');
       boost::iostreams::stream_buffer<boost::iostreams::array_source> buf(
           request.data(), request.size());

       std::istream input(&buf);
       std::string reponse;
       std::getline(input, reponse);
       return reponse + '\n';
   }
  ```

E.g. when running with `2323` and later `quit` command:

```
# (echo 2323; sleep 30; echo quit) | ./sotest
Port - 2323
Server start
Command: "quit"
OnAccept: Operation canceled
```

It does correctly accept multiple connections:

```
# for a in {1..10}; do printf "Message with random data $RANDOM\n" | nc localhost 2323; done
Message with random data 8002
Message with random data 28046
Message with random data 17943
Message with random data 17845
Message with random data 10832
Message with random data 20049
Message with random data 27593
Message with random data 18979
Message with random data 2773
Message with random data 31159
```

Comment: Added a deeper review with many simplifications. Tested and confirmed UBSAN/ASAN clean: https://wandbox.org/permlink/vq3oFBgqB9CpbQjD

Comment: I used strands - your approach using `atomic<bool>` looked valid to me because you only used it on a "logical strand", but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042

Comment: For convenience, all the files in a gist: https://gist.github.com/sehe/e26c33ce9c845966a83850b2dea3f207