# boost::asio::async_write_some - sequential function call

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am writing an application using boost.asio. I've an object of type `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` and (of course) I've `boost::asio::io_context` which `run`'s function was called from only one thread. For writing data to the socket there are a couple of ways but currently I use socket's function `async_write_some`, something like the code below:

```
void tcp_connection::write(packet_ptr packet)
{
    m_socket.async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer(packet->data(), packet->size()),
                              std::bind(&tcp_connection::on_write, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, packet));
}
```

There is another function in `boost::asio` namespace - `async_write`. And the documentation of `async_write` says:

> This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the stream's async_write_some function, and is known as a composed operation. The program must ensure that the stream performs no other write operations (such as async_write, the stream's async_write_some function, or any other composed operations that perform writes) until this operation completes.

In `async_write_some`'s documentation there is no such kind of 'caution'.

That's a little bit confusing to me and here I've got the following questions:

1. Is it safe to call `async_write_some` without waiting for the previous call to be finished? As far as I understood from boost's documentation I shouldn't do that with `async_write`, but what about `async_write_some`?
2. If yes, is the order in which the data is written to the socket the same as the functions were called? I mean if I called `async_write_some(packet1)` and `async_write_some(packet2)` - are the packets going to be written to the socket in the same order?
3. Which function I should use? What is the difference between them?
4. What is the reason that it's not safe to call `async_write` while the previous one hasn't finished yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. no; the reason for that is probably documented with the underlying sockets API (BSD/WinSock).
2. not applicable. Note that the order in which handlers are invoked *is* guaranteed to match the order in which they were posted, so you could solve it using an async chain of `async_write_some` calls where the completion handler posts the next write. This is known as an implicit strand (see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html and [Why do I need strand per connection when using boost::asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042)).
3. 99% of the time, use the free function. The difference is that it implements composed operation to send a "unit" of information, i.e. an entire buffer, message, or until a given completion condition is met.

   `async_write_some` is the lowest-level building block, which doesn't even guarantee to write all of the data: [remarks](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_write_some.html#boost_asio.reference.basic_stream_socket.async_write_some.remarks):

   > The write operation may not transmit all of the data to the peer.
   > Consider using the [`async_write`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write.html) function if you need to ensure that all
   > data is written before the asynchronous operation completes.
4. It's not unsafe¹ in the strictest sense. It just will not lead to correct results: this is because the order in which handlers are invoked leads to data being written to the socket in mixed-up order.

---

¹(unless you access the shared IO objects concurrently without synchronization)

Comment: Thank you for your response. boost::asio::io_context guarantees that my handlers will be executed only by the thread(s) that called run function. But it is true only for handlers, isn't it? Am I correct that boost::asio::io_context may execute both write operations at the same time?

Comment: Not since you run it on only one thread. Otherwise, yes, handlers may run concurrently and you have to make provisions (e.g. using a strand)

Comment: Thanks, I guess it's clear for me how handlers are being called. But could you please clarify - even in case if I call run from only one thread, asynchronous tasks may be executed on different threads? If I called async_write twice, io_context may execute both of them on two different threads and that's the reason why I should synchronize them?

Comment: No, they're run asynchronously, usually using library/kernel level async interfaces. In practice this means that the completions of (sub) operations may be interleaving. It's not so much "synchronizing" as "serializing (execution)" or "sequentializing".

Comment: In short, though concurrency and asynchrony are orthogonal concepts, they share some of the complicating concerns - for subtly different reasons.