# Is it safe that the one coroutine function working on multiple strand/thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20, boost-asio, coroutine

## Motivation

I'm writing a message broker using C++20 coroutine. The broker has some sessions (connections).
The broker deliver's message as follows:

```
sender(ss)       broker  receiver(sr)
   |               |           |
   | message       |           |
   |-------------->|           |
   |               | message   |
   |               |---------->|
   |               |           |
```

The delivery process is triggered by sender's session (ss). During the process, accessing receiver session (ss) is required.
ss and sr could woking on the different thread and different [strand](https://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html). How to switch the [strand](https://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html) well?

## Minimal code example to demonstrate the situation

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <syncstream>
#include <thread>
#include <cassert>

namespace as = boost::asio;

template <typename Executor>
struct session {
    session(Executor exe):str_{exe} {}
    void access() const {
        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << std::this_thread::get_id() << " access()" << std::endl;
        assert(str_.running_in_this_thread());
    }
    as::strand<Executor> str_;
};

int main() {
    as::io_context iocs;
    as::io_context iocr;
    auto guards = as::make_work_guard(iocs.get_executor());
    auto guardr = as::make_work_guard(iocr.get_executor());
    session ss{iocs.get_executor()};
    session sr{iocr.get_executor()};

    co_spawn(
        ss.str_,  // sender's strand
        [&] () -> as::awaitable<void> {
            std::osyncstream(std::cout) 
                << std::this_thread::get_id() 
                << " sender start deliver" 
                << std::endl;
            // need to access to receiver's resource to deliver
#if 0
            sr.access(); // assertion failed because this coroutine is
                         // working on sender's strand, not receiver's one
#endif
            // so dispatch to the receiver's strand
            co_await as::dispatch(sr.str_, as::use_awaitable);
#if 0
                         // B
            sr.access(); // assertion failed because this coroutine is
                         // working on sender's strand, not receiver's one
#endif
            // so dispatch to the receiver's strand
            co_await as::dispatch(as::bind_executor(sr.str_, as::use_awaitable));

            sr.access(); // working on receiver's thread. 
                         // This is expected behavior. 

            guards.reset();
            guardr.reset();
            co_return;
        },
        as::detached
    );
    std::thread ts {
        [&] {
            std::osyncstream(std::cout) << std::this_thread::get_id() << " sender thread" << std::endl;
            iocs.run();
        }
    };
    std::thread tr {
        [&] {
            std::osyncstream(std::cout) << std::this_thread::get_id() << " receiver thread" << std::endl;
            iocr.run();
        }
    };
    ts.join();
    tr.join();
}
```

godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/z8r6fYjj3

`session` has the strand `str_` and `access()` function. `access()` function expects the function is called on the `str_` to eliminate resource lock.

`co_spawn` itself is working of sender's strand.

## What I tried

### Direct call receiver's access()

It caused assertion failure. It is ovious because the code is working on sender's strand, not receiver's one.

### Use dispatch with receiver's strand as the first parameter (Executor)

It still caused assertion failure.
It is not clear for me. I guess that the process is switched to receiver's strand but co_await switched back to the sender's strand because co_spawn's executor is sender's strand. It is used as default executor. That is just my guessing.

### Use dispatch with bind_executor and its first argument (bind executor) is receiver's strand

It works as I expected.

```cpp
            // so dispatch to the receiver's strand
            co_await as::dispatch(as::bind_executor(sr.str_, as::use_awaitable));

            sr.access(); // working on receiver's thread. 
                         // This is expected behavior.
```

The part of code after co_await is working on receiver's strand even if co_spawn's executor is sender's strand.

However, I'm not sure it is safe. I suspect that it could be one apperence of undefined behavior.

If it is safe. I want to use this approach.

### Another approach

I read the code example of char server.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp20/coroutines/chat_server.cpp
It is very interesting. The session has two coroutines that are reader() and writer(). And the writer()'s async_write() is triggered by cancel of the never fired timer. It is a bit tricky. It is nicely avoid continuous async_write() call before the aync process is completed using queue.

However, im my case, the session has already been have queing mechanism internally. So this trick is too much for me.

## Summarize the question

### Question1

Is the following approach is safe ? Am I missing something important?

```cpp
co_spawn(
    base_strand,
    coroutine_function
);
```

```cpp
as::awaitable<void>
coroutine_function() {
    // basically working on base_strand.
    // ...

    co_await some_async_func(..., bind_executor(strand1, as::use_awaitable));
    // this part is working on strand1
    // ...

    co_await some_async_func(..., bind_executor(strand2, as::use_awaitable));
    // this part is working on strand2
    // ...

    co_await some_async_func(..., as::use_awaitable);
    // this part is working on base_strand
    // ...
}
```

### Question2

```cpp
co_await as::dispatch(sr.str_, as::use_awaitable);
```

```cpp
co_await as::dispatch(as::bind_executor(sr.str_, as::use_awaitable));
```

Why the first code isn't working on `sr.str_` ?

Comment: What is a strand?

Comment: strand is https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1 - Yes it is safe for Asio. A coroutine is an implicit strand because resumption is a linear chain of handlers. You can run them anywhere, including on strands.

Q2 - This is an oft-occurring confusion, e.g. [Using a boost asio strand as a 'mutex' does not work with coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76794580/using-a-boost-asio-strand-as-a-mutex-does-not-work-with-coroutines/76795293#76795293)

See also these explanations:

- [asio How to change the executor inside an awaitable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71987021/asio-how-to-change-the-executor-inside-an-awaitable/71991876#71991876)
- [Switch context in coroutine with boost::asio::post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74071288/switch-context-in-coroutine-with-boostasiopost/74075421#74075421)
- implementation mechanics [When must you pass io_context to boost::asio::spawn? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66731990/when-must-you-pass-io-context-to-boostasiospawn-c/66733239#66733239) and [boost::asio::bind_executor does not execute in strand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71475533/boostasiobind-executor-does-not-execute-in-strand/71475865#71475865)

Also look at the newer `asio::deferred` instead of `asio::use_awaitable` if you can: it's more efficient and less coroutine-specific.

Much simplified:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bed5d4d78eeaafe)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <syncstream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;

static int       tid_gen = 0;
thread_local int tid     = tid_gen++;

struct session {
    session(asio::any_io_executor exe) : strand_{exe} {}

    void access() const {
        std::osyncstream(std::cout) << tid << " access()" << std::endl;
        assert(strand_.running_in_this_thread());
    }

    asio::strand<asio::any_io_executor> strand_;
};

int main() {
    asio::thread_pool iocs(1), iocr(1);
    post(iocs, [] { std::osyncstream(std::cout) << tid << " sender thread" << std::endl; });
    post(iocr, [] { std::osyncstream(std::cout) << tid << " receiver thread" << std::endl; });
    session ss{iocs.get_executor()};
    session sr{iocr.get_executor()};

    co_spawn(
        ss.strand_, // sender's strand
        [&]() -> asio::awaitable<void> {
            std::osyncstream(std::cout) << tid << " sender start deliver" << std::endl;

            co_await asio::dispatch(asio::bind_executor(sr.strand_, asio::use_awaitable));

            sr.access();
            co_return;
        },
        asio::detached);

    iocs.join();
    iocr.join();
}
```

Printing e.g.

```
1 receiver thread
0 sender thread
0 sender start deliver
1 access()
```

Comment: Added a simplifying example. I have the suspicion that you'd really want to look at [Channels](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/channels.html) and the examples using concurrent_channel

Comment: Thanks you! I understand the concept of co_spawned coroutine function. I think that Channels are good replacement of write_msgs_ deque and infinity steady timer at [chat_server.cpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp20/coroutines/chat_server.cpp) example.
I'm developping a message broker that uses some asio based async functions. e.g. boost asio itself, mysql, redis, etc. Combining those async function efficiently and easy to understand. I need to further study C++20 coroutine overhead is ignoreable or not on my broker. BTW, tid trick is nice :) good to know

Comment: Anyway, I will write performance checking code that actually do the network(maybe loopback) communication using C++20 coroutine, Channels, callbacks (as baseline). I'm interested in the overhead of the mechanism itself but it might not be a dominant.

Comment: You can [ask for review comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) about ways to improve performance. In general, less strands, more specialization to an executor type (avoiding `any_io_executor`'s type erasure and dynamic allocation), also in general, avoiding cross-dispatch, avoiding unnecessary coro frames (e.g. with `deferred`) and using existing cancellation slots to coordinate tasks etc.

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *is for*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.