boost::asio compatible awaitable condition variable
I want to create a class that is compatible with boost::asio::awaitable that allows waiting on a condition variable asynchronously.
This is my attempt, but I honestly have no idea what I am doing
template <class T>
class ConditionVariableAwaiter : public boost::asio::awaitable<T> {
public:
   ConditionVariableAwaiter(std::condition_variable& cv, std::mutex& mtx, std::function<bool(void)> && ready, const std::chrono::seconds timeout = std::chrono::seconds(0))
      : _cv(cv), _mutex(mtx), _ready(std::move(ready)), _handle(nullptr), _timeout(timeout) {}

   ConditionVariableAwaiter(ConditionVariableAwaiter && other) noexcept :
   _cv(std::move(other._cv)),
   _mutex(std::move(other._cv)),
   _ready(std::move(other._ready)),
   _handle(std::move(other._handle)),
   _timeout(std::move(other._timeout)) {}

   ConditionVariableAwaiter &operator=(ConditionVariableAwaiter && other) noexcept {
      _cv = std::move(other._cv);
      _mutex = std::move(other._cv);
      _ready = std::move(other._ready);
      _handle = std::move(other._handle);
      _timeout = std::move(other._timeout);
   }

   ConditionVariableAwaiter(const ConditionVariableAwaiter & other) = delete;
   ConditionVariableAwaiter &operator=(const ConditionVariableAwaiter & other) = delete;

   bool await_ready() const noexcept {
      return _ready();
   }

   void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> handle) {
      std::unique_lock lock(_mutex);
      _handle = handle;
      if (_timeout.count() == 0) {
         _cv.wait(lock, [this] { return _ready(); });
         _handle.resume();
      }
      else {
         if (_cv.wait_for(lock, _timeout, [this] { return _ready(); })) {
            _handle.resume();
         }
         else {
            _timedOut = true;
            _handle.resume();
         }
      }
   }

   bool await_resume() const noexcept {
      return _timedOut;
   }

   void notify() {
      std::lock_guard lock(_mutex);
      _cv.notify_all();
      if (_handle && _ready()) {
         _handle.resume();
      }
   }

   bool timedOut() const {
      return _timedOut;
   }

private:
   std::condition_variable& _cv;
   std::mutex& _mutex;
   std::function<bool(void)> _ready;
   std::coroutine_handle<> _handle;
   std::chrono::seconds _timeout;
   bool _timedOut = false;
};

When I try to call co_await in a function boost::asio::awaitable<std::optional<ValueType>> waitCoro(const KeyType &key), I get the error:
error: use of deleted function ‘boost::asio::awaitable<T, Executor>::awaitable(const boost::asio::awaitable<T, Executor>&) [with T = std::optional<int>; Executor = boost::asio::any_io_executor]’
[build]   143 |          co_await awaiter;

The awaiter var in question was created like this:
ConditionVariableAwaiter<std::optional<ValueType>> awaiter(_cv, _mutex, [this] { return !_map.empty() || _cancelled; });
EDIT
So instead of trying to make an awaitable on a condition variable (the call to wait is still blocking as someone pointed out) I used boost steady_timers to async wait, and then when I need to signal to the waiting thread to wake up I just cancel the timer.
The only minor issue is that co_await _timer->async_wait(boost::asio::use_awaitable); has to be wrapped in a try catch because it will throw a operation_aborted when canceled. Is there any way to avoid the exception? I try passing a system_error object but it doesn't like it.

Usually people use a deadline timer (at timepoint::max) which can be manually "reset" (cancel() or cancel_one()). Can you show us how you expect to use this class? I cannot wrap my head why you inherit a coro promise type and store a handle. Perhaps my lowlevel c++20 coro fu is lacking, but an example may help

Also, I see blocking waits for the cv_. That's not what async waiting means to me. Older example of the timer approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76310252/c-boost-asio-building-a-conditional-variable-using-io-context-strand. Also see the SAM primitives linked e.g. here https://github.com/boostorg/cobalt/issues/143 (the entire discussion seems to be precisely what you are discovering)

Oh, and don't forget channels, there's even mutual exclusion samples: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp20_examples.html

Hey guys thanks for the input. I need to stress that I really do not know what I am doing here. What I want to do is create an async message queue so that threads can co_await on it until a message is pushed. The sync wait to do this is with a condition variable and a mutex. I ended up using a timer like suggested, although I didnt use max() and because I actually need it to timeout at some point. Your point about channels is also interesting, I will have to look into it.


The only minor issue is that co_await _timer->async_wait(boost::asio::use_awaitable); has to be wrapped in a try catch because it will throw a operation_aborted when canceled. Is there any way to avoid the exception? I try passing a system_error object but it doesn't like it.

You can use token adaptors like asio::as_tuple or asio::redirect_error to get the error code instead of having co_await throw the system_error exception.
In relation to using timers: be sure to take care about race condition windows: Cancelling boost asio deadline timer safely

Yes! the redirect_error works: timer.async_wait(boost::asio::redirect_error(boost::asio::use_awaitable, ec)). Thanks for the input about canceling the timer as well. I have worked with the timers alot so I do understand more about how they work. I am aware of the fact that cancelling only works when a timer has been started but the completion handler not yet invoked. learned that the hard a while ago haha
