# Boost Beast Async Websocket Server How to interface with session?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-beast

So I don't know why but I can't wrap my head around the boost Beast websocket server and how you can (or should) interact with it.

The basic program I made looks like this, across 2 classes (`WebSocketListener` and `WebSocketSession`)
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/async/websocket_server_async.cpp

Everything works great, I can connect, and it echos messages.  We will only ever have 1 active session, and I'm struggling to understand how I can interface with this session from outside its class, in my int main() for example or another class that may be responsible for issuing read/writes.  We will be using a simple Command design pattern of commands async coming into a buffer that get processed against hardware and then async_write back out the results.  The reading and queuing is straight forward and will be done in the `WebsocketSession`, but everything I see for write is just reading/writing directly inside the session and not getting external input.

I've seen examples using things like `boost::asio::async_write(socket, buffer, ...)` but I'm struggling to understand how I get a reference to said socket when the session is created by the listener itself.

Comment: If you want to do something different instead of echo the message you can change the code after "// Echo the message"?

Comment: The problem is then the write is always tied to a read,  I need to be able to write independently from other locations in my code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of depending on a socket from outside of the session, I'd *depend on your program logic* to implement the session.

That's because the session (connection) will govern its own lifetime, arriving spontaneously and potentially disconnecting spontaneously. Your hardware, most likely, doesn't.

So, borrowing the concept of "Dependency Injection" tell your listener about your application logic, and then call into that from the session. (The listener will "inject" the dependency into each newly created session).

Let's start from a simplified/modernized version of your linked example.

Now, where we prepare a response, you want your own logic injected, so let's write it how we would imagine it:

```
void on_read(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
    if (ec == websocket::error::closed) return;
    if (ec.failed())                    return fail(ec, "read");

    // Process the message
    response_ = logic_->Process(beast::buffers_to_string(buffer_));

    ws_.async_write(
        net::buffer(response_),
        beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_write, shared_from_this()));
}
```

Here we declare the members and initialize them from the constructor:

```
    std::string                          response_;
    std::shared_ptr<AppDomain::Logic>    logic_;

  public:
    explicit session(tcp::socket&&                     socket,
                     std::shared_ptr<AppDomain::Logic> logic)
        : ws_(std::move(socket))
        , logic_(logic) {}
```

Now, we need to inject the listener with the logic so we can pass it along:

```
class listener : public std::enable_shared_from_this<listener> {
    net::any_io_executor              ex_;
    tcp::acceptor                     acceptor_;
    std::shared_ptr<AppDomain::Logic> logic_;

  public:
    listener(net::any_io_executor ex, tcp::endpoint endpoint,
             std::shared_ptr<AppDomain::Logic> logic)
        : ex_(ex)
        , acceptor_(ex)
        , logic_(logic) {
```

So that we can pass it along:

```
void on_accept(beast::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
    if (ec) {
        fail(ec, "accept");
    } else {
        std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket), logic_)->run();
    }

    // Accept another connection
    do_accept();
}
```

Now making the real logic in main:

```
auto logic = std::make_shared<AppDomain::Logic>("StackOverflow Demo/");

try {
    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::thread_pool ioc(threads);

    std::make_shared<listener>(ioc.get_executor(),
                               tcp::endpoint{address, port}, logic)
        ->run();

    ioc.join();
} catch (beast::system_error const& se) {
    fail(se.code(), "listener");
}
```

### Demo Logic

Just for fun, let's implement some random logic, that might be implemented in hardware in the future:

```
namespace AppDomain {
    struct Logic {
        std::string banner;
        Logic(std::string msg) : banner(std::move(msg)) {}

        std::string Process(std::string request) {
            std::cout << "Processing: " << std::quoted(request) << std::endl;

            std::string result;

            auto fold = [&result](auto op, double initial) {
                return [=, &result](auto& ctx) {
                    auto& args = _attr(ctx);
                    auto  v = accumulate(args.begin(), args.end(), initial, op);
                    result  = "Fold:" + std::to_string(v);
                };
            };

            auto invalid = [&result](auto& ctx) {
                result = "Invalid Command: " + _attr(ctx);
            };

            using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
            auto args = rule<void, std::vector<double>>{} = '(' >> double_ % ',' >> ')';
            auto add = "adding"      >> args[fold(std::plus<>{}, 0)];
            auto mul = "multiplying" >> args[fold(std::multiplies<>{}, 1)];
            auto err = lexeme[+char_][invalid];

            phrase_parse(begin(request), end(request), add | mul | err, blank);

            return banner + result;
        }
    };
} // namespace AppDomain
```

Now you can see it in action: **[Full Listing](https://godbolt.org/z/nPrW3Kj7Y)**

[image]

### Where To Go From Here

What if you need multiple responses for one request?

You need a queue. I usually call those `outbox` so [searching for `outbox_`, `_outbox` etc](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20%20%20outbox_) will give lots of examples.

Those examples will also show how to deal with other situations where writes can be "externally initiated", and how to safely enqueue those. Perhaps a very engaging example is here [How to batch send unsent messages in asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71141575/how-to-batch-send-unsent-messages-in-asio/71145869#71145869)

#### Listing For Reference

In case the links go dead in the future:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <filesystem>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

static std::string g_app_name = "app-logic-service";

#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>  // just for our demo logic
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp> // idem
#include <numeric>                  // idem

namespace AppDomain {
    struct Logic {
        std::string banner;
        Logic(std::string msg) : banner(std::move(msg)) {}

        std::string Process(std::string request) {
            std::string result;

            auto fold = [&result](auto op, double initial) {
                return [=, &result](auto& ctx) {
                    auto& args = _attr(ctx);
                    auto  v = accumulate(args.begin(), args.end(), initial, op);
                    result  = "Fold:" + std::to_string(v);
                };
            };

            auto invalid = [&result](auto& ctx) {
                result = "Invalid Command: " + _attr(ctx);
            };

            using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
            auto args = rule<void, std::vector<double>>{} = '(' >> double_ % ',' >> ')';
            auto add = "adding"      >> args[fold(std::plus<>{}, 0)];
            auto mul = "multiplying" >> args[fold(std::multiplies<>{}, 1)];
            auto err = lexeme[+char_][invalid];

            phrase_parse(begin(request), end(request), add | mul | err, blank);

            return banner + result;
        }
    };
} // namespace AppDomain

namespace beast     = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http      = beast::http;          // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket;     // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net       = boost::asio;          // from <boost/asio.hpp>
using tcp           = boost::asio::ip::tcp; // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

// Report a failure
void fail(beast::error_code ec, char const* what) {
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}

class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
    websocket::stream<beast::tcp_stream> ws_;
    beast::flat_buffer                   buffer_;
    std::string                          response_;
    std::shared_ptr<AppDomain::Logic>    logic_;

public:
    explicit session(tcp::socket&&                     socket,
                    std::shared_ptr<AppDomain::Logic> logic)
        : ws_(std::move(socket))
        , logic_(logic) {}

    void run() {
        // Get on the correct executor
        // strand for thread safety
        dispatch(
            ws_.get_executor(),
            beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_run, shared_from_this()));
    }

private:
    void on_run() {
        // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(
            beast::role_type::server));

        // Set a decorator to change the Server of the handshake
        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
            [](websocket::response_type& res) {
                res.set(http::field::server,
                        std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) + " " +
                            g_app_name);
            }));

        // Accept the websocket handshake
        ws_.async_accept(
            beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_accept, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_accept(beast::error_code ec) {
        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "accept");

        do_read();
    }

    void do_read() {
        ws_.async_read(
            buffer_,
            beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_read, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_read(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
        if (ec == websocket::error::closed) return;
        if (ec.failed())                    return fail(ec, "read");

        // Process the message
        auto request = boost::algorithm::trim_copy(
            beast::buffers_to_string(buffer_.data()));

        std::cout << "Processing: " << std::quoted(request) << " from "
                << beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).socket().remote_endpoint()
                << std::endl;

        response_ = logic_->Process(request);

        ws_.async_write(
            net::buffer(response_),
            beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_write, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_write(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "write");

        // Clear the buffer
        buffer_.consume(buffer_.size());

        // Do another read
        do_read();
    }
};

// Accepts incoming connections and launches the sessions
class listener : public std::enable_shared_from_this<listener> {
    net::any_io_executor              ex_;
    tcp::acceptor                     acceptor_;
    std::shared_ptr<AppDomain::Logic> logic_;

public:
    listener(net::any_io_executor ex, tcp::endpoint endpoint,
            std::shared_ptr<AppDomain::Logic> logic)
        : ex_(ex)
        , acceptor_(ex)
        , logic_(logic) {
        acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol());
        acceptor_.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        acceptor_.bind(endpoint);
        acceptor_.listen(tcp::acceptor::max_listen_connections);
    }

    // Start accepting incoming connections
    void run() { do_accept(); }

private:
    void do_accept() {
        // The new connection gets its own strand
        acceptor_.async_accept(make_strand(ex_),
                            beast::bind_front_handler(&listener::on_accept,
                                                        shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_accept(beast::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
        if (ec) {
            fail(ec, "accept");
        } else {
            std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket), logic_)->run();
        }

        // Accept another connection
        do_accept();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    g_app_name = std::filesystem::path(argv[0]).filename();

    if (argc != 4) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << g_app_name << " <address> <port> <threads>\n"
                << "Example:\n"
                << "    " << g_app_name << " 0.0.0.0 8080 1\n";
        return 1;
    }
    auto const address = net::ip::make_address(argv[1]);
    auto const port    = static_cast<uint16_t>(std::atoi(argv[2]));
    auto const threads = std::max<int>(1, std::atoi(argv[3]));

    auto logic = std::make_shared<AppDomain::Logic>("StackOverflow Demo/");

    try {
        // The io_context is required for all I/O
        net::thread_pool ioc(threads);

        std::make_shared<listener>(ioc.get_executor(),
                                tcp::endpoint{address, port}, logic)
            ->run();

        ioc.join();
    } catch (beast::system_error const& se) {
        fail(se.code(), "listener");
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

In response to the comments I reified the outbox pattern again. Note some of the comments in the code.

**[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/bv4EPTWd6)**

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <filesystem>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

static std::string g_app_name = "app-logic-service";

#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>  // just for our demo logic
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp> // idem
#include <numeric>                  // idem

namespace AppDomain {
    struct Logic {
        std::string banner;
        Logic(std::string msg) : banner(std::move(msg)) {}

        std::string Process(std::string request) {
            std::string result;

            auto fold = [&result](auto op, double initial) {
                return [=, &result](auto& ctx) {
                    auto& args = _attr(ctx);
                    auto  v = accumulate(args.begin(), args.end(), initial, op);
                    result  = "Fold:" + std::to_string(v);
                };
            };

            auto invalid = [&result](auto& ctx) {
                result = "Invalid Command: " + _attr(ctx);
            };

            using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
            auto args = rule<void, std::vector<double>>{} = '(' >> double_ % ',' >> ')';
            auto add = "adding"      >> args[fold(std::plus<>{}, 0)];
            auto mul = "multiplying" >> args[fold(std::multiplies<>{}, 1)];
            auto err = lexeme[+char_][invalid];

            phrase_parse(begin(request), end(request), add | mul | err, blank);

            return banner + result;
        }
    };
} // namespace AppDomain

namespace beast     = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http      = beast::http;          // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket;     // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net       = boost::asio;          // from <boost/asio.hpp>
using tcp           = boost::asio::ip::tcp; // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

// Report a failure
void fail(beast::error_code ec, char const* what) {
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}

class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
    websocket::stream<beast::tcp_stream> ws_;
    beast::flat_buffer                   buffer_;
    std::shared_ptr<AppDomain::Logic>    logic_;

public:
    explicit session(tcp::socket&&                     socket,
                    std::shared_ptr<AppDomain::Logic> logic)
        : ws_(std::move(socket))
        , logic_(logic) {}

    void run() {
        // Get on the correct executor
        // strand for thread safety
        dispatch(
            ws_.get_executor(),
            beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_run, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void post_message(std::string msg) {
        post(ws_.get_executor(),
            [self = shared_from_this(), this, msg = std::move(msg)] {
                do_post_message(std::move(msg));
            });
    }

private:
    void on_run() {
        // on the strand
        // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(
            beast::role_type::server));

        // Set a decorator to change the Server of the handshake
        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
            [](websocket::response_type& res) {
                res.set(http::field::server,
                        std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) + " " +
                            g_app_name);
            }));

        // Accept the websocket handshake
        ws_.async_accept(
            beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_accept, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_accept(beast::error_code ec) {
        // on the strand
        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "accept");

        do_read();
    }

    void do_read() {
        // on the strand
        buffer_.clear();

        ws_.async_read(
            buffer_,
            beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_read, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_read(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
        // on the strand
        if (ec == websocket::error::closed) return;
        if (ec.failed())                    return fail(ec, "read");

        // Process the message
        auto request = boost::algorithm::trim_copy(
            beast::buffers_to_string(buffer_.data()));

        std::cout << "Processing: " << std::quoted(request) << " from "
                << beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).socket().remote_endpoint()
                << std::endl;

        do_post_message(logic_->Process(request)); // already on the strand

        do_read();
    }

    std::deque<std::string> _outbox;

    void do_post_message(std::string msg) {
        // on the strand
        _outbox.push_back(std::move(msg));

        if (_outbox.size() == 1)
            do_write_loop();
    }

    void do_write_loop() {
        // on the strand
        if (_outbox.empty())
            return;

        ws_.async_write( //
            net::buffer(_outbox.front()),
            [self = shared_from_this(), this] //
            (beast::error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
                // on the strand
                boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

                if (ec)
                    return fail(ec, "write");

                _outbox.pop_front();
                do_write_loop();
            });
    }
};

// Accepts incoming connections and launches the sessions
class listener : public std::enable_shared_from_this<listener> {
    net::any_io_executor              ex_;
    tcp::acceptor                     acceptor_;
    std::shared_ptr<AppDomain::Logic> logic_;

public:
    listener(net::any_io_executor ex, tcp::endpoint endpoint,
            std::shared_ptr<AppDomain::Logic> logic)
        : ex_(ex)
        , acceptor_(make_strand(ex)) // NOTE to guard sessions_
        , logic_(logic) {
        acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol());
        acceptor_.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        acceptor_.bind(endpoint);
        acceptor_.listen(tcp::acceptor::max_listen_connections);
    }

    // Start accepting incoming connections
    void run() { do_accept(); }

    void broadcast(std::string msg) {
        post(acceptor_.get_executor(),
            beast::bind_front_handler(&listener::do_broadcast,
                                    shared_from_this(), std::move(msg)));
    }

private:
    using handle_t = std::weak_ptr<session>;
    std::list<handle_t> sessions_;

    void do_broadcast(std::string const& msg) {
        for (auto handle : sessions_)
            if (auto sess = handle.lock())
                sess->post_message(msg);
    }

    void do_accept() {
        // The new connection gets its own strand
        acceptor_.async_accept(make_strand(ex_),
                            beast::bind_front_handler(&listener::on_accept,
                                                        shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_accept(beast::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
        // on the strand
        if (ec) {
            fail(ec, "accept");
        } else {
            auto sess = std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket), logic_);
            sessions_.emplace_back(sess);
            // optionally:
            sessions_.remove_if(std::mem_fn(&handle_t::expired));
            sess->run();
        }

        // Accept another connection
        do_accept();
    }
};

static void emulate_hardware_stuff(std::shared_ptr<listener> srv) {
    using std::this_thread::sleep_for;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    // Extremely simplistic. Instead I'd recommend `steady_timer` with
    // `_async_wait` here, but since I'm just making a sketch...
    unsigned i = 0;

    while (true) {
        sleep_for(1s);
        srv->broadcast("Hardware thing #" + std::to_string(++i));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    g_app_name = std::filesystem::path(argv[0]).filename();

    if (argc != 4) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << g_app_name << " <address> <port> <threads>\n"
                << "Example:\n"
                << "    " << g_app_name << " 0.0.0.0 8080 1\n";
        return 1;
    }
    auto const address = net::ip::make_address(argv[1]);
    auto const port    = static_cast<uint16_t>(std::atoi(argv[2]));
    auto const threads = std::max<int>(1, std::atoi(argv[3]));

    auto logic = std::make_shared<AppDomain::Logic>("StackOverflow Demo/");

    try {
        // The io_context is required for all I/O
        net::thread_pool ioc(threads);

        auto srv = std::make_shared<listener>( //
            ioc.get_executor(),                     //
            tcp::endpoint{address, port},           //
            logic);

        srv->run();

        std::thread something_hardware(emulate_hardware_stuff, srv);

        ioc.join();
        something_hardware.join();
    } catch (beast::system_error const& se) {
        fail(se.code(), "listener");
    }
}
```

With Live Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The issue we have is we arent doing a 1 to 1 in and out.  We are asynch taking in messages from our web client and queueing them in a buffer, some of these messages will have timers, which will tell the server to poll the hardware every N ms and return the response.  The problem im having is every example links the server write to a server read, which we dont want.  1 incoming message results in it being on a circular buffer that would send out an updated message if the hw state has changed every 100ms for example.  A pub/sub type model sort of(but not quite)

Comment: Have you... read the answer? I link to extensive ideas and examples. Of course, I can whip it up another time, but it could be a waste of time because I've done it so many times before on this very site.

Comment: (Posted an update the answer that integrates the pattern into the program)

Comment: Hey @sehe is there any way to get this to work with a std::dequeue<const std::string> ? If I use an immutable std::string, the compile fails.

Comment: @JoshMenzel standard containers require mutable elements. The pattern you'd usually see is to share messages as `shared_ptr<Message const>`. That works in a standard container (adaptor).