# Boost Asio async client

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, c++20, boost-asio

I'm trying to write a async client using Boost asio,
I wrote the following code,

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>
namespace json = boost::json;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace this_coro = asio::this_coro;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace asio::experimental::awaitable_operators;

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;




template <typename T> using Defer = asio::deferred_t::as_default_on_t<T>;
using Socket = Defer<tcp::socket>;
using Acceptor = Defer<tcp::acceptor>;



using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class TCPClient {
public:
    TCPClient(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
        : io_service_(io_service), socket_(io_service) {
        connect(endpoint_iterator);
    }

    void write(const std::string& message) {
        io_service_.post(boost::bind(&TCPClient::do_write, this, message));
    }

    void close() {
        io_service_.post(boost::bind(&TCPClient::do_close, this));
    }

private:
    void connect(tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator) {
        boost::asio::async_connect(socket_, endpoint_iterator,
            boost::bind(&TCPClient::handle_connect, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error) {
        if (!error) {
            cout << "connected" << endl;
            write("Hello, World!");
            read();
        }
        else {
            cout << "connection failed" << endl;
        }
    }

    void do_write(const std::string& message) {
        boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
            boost::asio::buffer(message),
            boost::bind(&TCPClient::handle_write, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error) {
        if (!error) {
            cout << "write successfully" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "write failed " << error << endl;
        }
    }

    void read() {
        socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
            boost::bind(&TCPClient::handle_read, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

        //socket_.async_read_some(buf.prepare(1024),
        //    boost::bind(&TCPClient::handle_read, this,
        //        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        //        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

    void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (!error) {
            std::cout << "Received: " << bytes_transferred << std::endl;
            read();
        }
        else {
            // Handle the error
            std::cout << "read failed " << error << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void do_close() {
        socket_.close();
    }

    boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
    tcp::socket socket_;
    enum { max_length = 1024 };
    char data_[max_length] = { 0 };
    boost::asio::streambuf buf;
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve("localhost", "8989");
    TCPClient client(io_service, endpoint_iterator);
    io_service.run();

    while (1) {}

    return 0;
}
```

The client can connect successfully and the handler is being called. Using wireshark I can also see that write() function sends "Hello, World" message and gets a reply back, but neither of write or read handlers are getting called.

I tried different stuff saw different sample codes but I couldn't figure it out. Also tried to write the same code using *coroutine* and the code can be found below but, I'm new to async sockets and Boost Asio and I wasn't sure what I'm still doing(But trying hard to get there),

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/detached.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/use_awaitable.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::awaitable;
using asio::co_spawn;
using asio::detached;
using asio::use_awaitable;

awaitable<void> connectAndCommunicate() {
    try {
        asio::io_context io_context;
        tcp::socket socket(io_context);

        co_await socket.async_connect(tcp::endpoint(asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 12345), use_awaitable);

        std::string message = "Hello, World!";
        co_await asio::async_write(socket, asio::buffer(message), use_awaitable);

        char data[128];
        std::size_t length = co_await socket.async_read_some(asio::buffer(data), use_awaitable);
        std::cout << "Received: " << std::string(data, length) << std::endl;

    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context io_context;
    co_spawn(io_context, connectAndCommunicate(), detached);
    io_context.run();
    return 0;
}
```

I would appreciate more experienced developers to point out my mistakes and how is best to do what I'm trying to do.

Thanks

Comment: don't create a new `io_context` in the coroutine. Instead pass the `io_context` from the main function as reference or an executor created from the context by copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First Version Review

1. don't use using namespace
2. don't use boost::bind, and certainly not the obsolete `boost/bind.hpp` include
3. don't include a ton of unneeded headers, drop unused type aliases
4. use abbreviated namespaces that you have
5. - use `io_context` instead of deprecated `io_service`
   - don't pass around references to io contexts; instead use executors
6. suggest to not leak implementation details in the interface (take host/port as constructor arguments, not some specific kind of iterator)
7. when on the strand, don't need to `post`, so in `handle_connect` do `do_write()`, instead of `write()`

Now we're down to 70 lines, from 120: **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02157ef7117a8db2)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::placeholders;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

static std::string const hello_message = "Hello World!";

class TCPClient {
  public:
    TCPClient(asio::io_context& ioc, std::string const& host, std::string const& port) : socket_(ioc) {
        tcp::resolver resolver(ioc);
        connect(resolver.resolve(host, port));
    }

    void write(std::string const& message) {
        post(socket_.get_executor(), std::bind(&TCPClient::do_write, this, message));
    }

    void close() { post(socket_.get_executor(), std::bind(&TCPClient::do_close, this)); }

  private:
    void connect(tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator) {
        async_connect(socket_, endpoint_iterator, std::bind(&TCPClient::handle_connect, this, _1));
    }

    void handle_connect(error_code ec) {
        if (!ec) {
            std::cout << "connected" << std::endl;
            do_write(hello_message);
            read();
        } else {
            std::cout << "connection failed (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void do_write(std::string const& message) {
        async_write(socket_, asio::buffer(message), std::bind(&TCPClient::handle_write, this, _1));
    }

    void handle_write(error_code ec) { std::cout << "write " << ec.message() << std::endl; }

    void read() {
        socket_.async_read_some(asio::buffer(data_), std::bind(&TCPClient::handle_read, this, _1, _2));

        // socket_.async_read_some(buf.prepare(1024), std::bind(&TCPClient::handle_read, this, _1, _2));
    }

    void handle_read(error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
        std::cout << "Read " << ec.message() << " (" << bytes_transferred << ")" << std::endl;
        if (!ec) {
            std::cout << "Received: " << bytes_transferred << std::endl;
            read();
        } else {
            // Handle the error
        }
    }

    void do_close() { socket_.close(); }

    tcp::socket            socket_;
    std::array<char, 1024> data_{0};
    // asio::streambuf     buf;
};

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    TCPClient        client(ioc, "localhost", "8989");
    ioc.run();
}
```

I may have inadvertantly fixed a problem that I didn't consciously mention, but to me it looks like it Just Works(TM):

[image]

### Second Version Review

That was a LOT cleaner already! I'd suggest

- drop the extra `io_context`, you're IN a coroutine, there is by definition a context. Get the executor from `this_coro`
- using `deferred` over `use_awaitable` for efficiency
- not using raw C arrays

To be closer to the first listing:

- Use the same buffer size
- Also take the host/port information and resolve it like in the first listing
- Loop on the reads

We get: **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d337eb5ae10d2a70)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/use_awaitable.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
namespace asio = boost::asio;

asio::awaitable<void> connectAndCommunicate(std::string host, std::string port) {
    try {
        auto ex = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
        auto token = asio::deferred;

        tcp::socket s(ex);
        tcp::resolver resolver(ex);
        co_await async_connect(s, co_await resolver.async_resolve(host, port, token), token);

        std::string message = "Hello, World!";
        co_await asio::async_write(s, asio::buffer(message), token);

        for (;;) {
            std::array<char, 1024> buf;
            auto length = co_await s.async_read_some(asio::buffer(buf), token);
            std::cout << "Received: " << quoted(std::string_view(buf.data(), length)) << std::endl;
        }
    } catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << se.code().message() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    co_spawn(ioc, connectAndCommunicate("127.0.0.1", "8989"), asio::detached);
    ioc.run();
}
```

[image]

- I'd consider making `deferred` the default executor. Ironically, the first code listing had those type aliases defined where they weren't even relevant :) **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a166739ba726b3b)**

### Loose Ends

Things glossed over because they weren't part of your question:

- strands and output message queueing (you don't have multiple output messages anyways now)
- message framing. `async_read_some` is a poor method if you need to interpret messages. You will get partial/concatenated messages. This is why composed operations and dynamic buffers exist.
- error handling. I slightly improved it, but you need to be aware of partial success (especially with composed reads, but perhaps  `async_read_some` can return bytes **and** EOF all in itself)

Comment: I already see what I did wrong, and I'm grateful for that.
- Can you please explain about "strands and output message queueing"?
- What do you suggest over `async_read_some` for reading unstructured data? In this example it was for texts, but I will have raw data in the project I'm working on.

Comment: @sehe As always, a detailed and useful answer taking into account a deep and up-to-date knowledge of the matter. You are an incredible valuable source of information when asking questions about boost!

Comment: I'm totally agree with you @JakobStark. and Thank you again sehe

Comment: @ Jelal Strands [when/why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12801042/85371), [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html)).  Queuing: [e.g. and many other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71113183/85371). @JakobStark Cheers!

Comment: What is the different in using Boost asio with coroutines vs handlers? Coroutine provide concurrency, is the concurrency provided when using callbacks?

Comment: They're exactly the same, except coroutines use the C++20 language features to have much nicer syntax.

Comment: Even async calls in Boost Beast are the same?

Comment: Yes. You can see it in the code: you're calling the same functions. Just with a different completion token

Comment: I'm rereading your answers and checking again the codes, but it seems the first example in your question doesn't solve the problem. The handler still doesn't get called!

Comment: Which handler doesn't get called?

Comment: Sorry, the read handler.

Comment: But... You can see it is getting called. There's a live demo. And it prints output from `handle_read`. So I guess, my code does solve the problem, but you came up with different code where it doesn't?

Comment: Yeah I see the gif, but i just copy and paste the code and build it in VS2022. :/ I get Debug Assertion Failed!

Expression: cannot dereference string iterator because the iterator was invalidated(e.g. rellocation occured, or the string was destroyed)

Comment: Oh wow. That's completely different from "read_handler doesn't get called". Let me check... Yeah, sorry I forgot to fix the message buffer (fixed now). It really slipped my mind because of the mentioned Loose End "strands and output message queueing (you don't have multiple output messages anyways now)" - it wasn't all overkill. Anways, here's what actual message queueing could look like: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b19a06c98ef64fa7

Answer (score 0):

asio::io_context::run() exits when your service runs out of tasks.

Try this:

```
int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve("localhost", "8989");
    TCPClient client(io_service, endpoint_iterator);

    // io_service.run();  // this exits when no more tasks, so 
                          // is useless unless you use a work_guard
c                        // or continuously call run.

   // try this instead.
    auto wg = boost::asio::make_work_guard(io_context);
    io_service.run();

    // the infinite loop is not necessary in this case.

    //while (1) {
    //}

    return 0;
}
```

You could also try something a bit like this, so you can gracefully close your client

```
    // _not_ using work_guard, check (quasi)simultaneoulsy for keyboard 
    // input and async operations
    char c;
    while (!std::cin.readsome(&c, 1)) {  // probably not the best way to get 
                                         // kb input, but good enough for a playground.
        io_service.poll();  
    }

    client.close();
    io_service.run();   // make sure all pending async operations terminate.
```