# How does Boost's async read/write/accept work in a multithreaded environment?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, boost

I am currently writing a HTTP server. It blocks while waiting for socket-data (using boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor async_accept). Then when data is available creates a Session to handle the incoming request. The Session object calls Boost's http:async_read, a process_request method I wrote, then http::async_write.

We are trying to multithread the server. One idea would be to spawn X number of threads, all executing the start_accept function and listening on the same socket. Yet, I am not sure if this works using the Boost libraries (and can't figure it out from the docs).

TLDR; how does the Boost async read/write/accept functions work? Intuitively, I would think the OS routes incoming data to one of the threads, if each thread is blocking with async_accept. Are the async methods blocking across threads (and so thread safe)?

Here is the example where I am calling async_accept, then calling the Session object.

```
void Server::start_accept()
{
  // Start acceptor.
  m_acceptor.async_accept(m_socket, [&](beast::error_code error_code)
  {
    // After the accept operation completes
    if (!error_code) 
    {
      // Constructs a Session object then runs start()
      std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(m_socket), m_server_params)->start();
    }
    
    start_accept(); // Accept new request.
  });
}
```

I am envisioning some wrapper function that runs as follows:

```
void Server::start_multithreaded_server()
{
  // Spawn X threads
  create_thread(start_accept)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run the io-service on multiple threads.

From there, you don't have to change a thing. The async_accept will be invoking the completion handler on any of the service threads.

Then since the only thing you do is initiate async operations via `Session::start()` the next `async_accept` will be posted immediately.

> If for some reason you **are** doing work that blocks the service thread for non-trivial amount of time, e.g. in the `Session` constructor, that's a design smell (**don't do that**). But, still, if that were the case, you might move the socket first, and call `start_accept` even before you construct the `Session`.

Keep in mind that in a multi-threaded environment you will want to have all operations in the session on a (logical) strand. See [Why do I need strand per connection when using boost::asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042)

For inspiration you can look at the various server examples. Notably all of the server examples here https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/examples.html#beast.examples.servers are multi-threaded exactly as shown here, but show

- the creation of threads

  ```
   // Run the I/O service on the requested number of threads
   std::vector<std::thread> v;
   v.reserve(threads - 1);
   for(auto i = threads - 1; i > 0; --i)
       v.emplace_back(
       [&ioc]
       {
           ioc.run();
       });
   ioc.run();
  ```
- the organization of strands per session