# boost::asio udp socket read and write

Tags: c++, sockets, asynchronous, udp, boost-asio

I need an advice with the situation

I'm doing a udp async multicast **transiver**:

- he can accepts data from multicast group
- he can send data to multicast group

Data is sent in the following cases:

- async_receive_from -> callback -> async_send (in the same thread)
- by **external** timer -> async_send(in another thread)

1. I use *one* socket for *receive and send*.
   Do I need synchronize async_receive_from and async_send_to from external timer?
   booast::asio doc says that objects are unsafe. My solution is use a ioserivce post/dispatch for external timer data, that  async_send_to call in the same thread
2. If I make *two* sockets - one for read, one for thread, who works this one multicast groud. Do I need synchronize this?

P.S. I'm using one thread ioservice::run

Answer (score 1):

As soon as an external timer is involved likely a strand is required for synchronization. The only exception is when the service is restricted to a single thread already - and the "external timer" trigger originates from that same thread. This is called the implicit strand.

Comment: Thank you, some more info -> I using one thread ioservice::run


1) Why my solution with post is wrong? I think about data was keep in lambda and write, when asio call this


2) In asio doc 
> Synchronous send, send_to, receive, receive_from, and connect operations are thread safe with respect to each other

What about async_read \ write?
Do i need strand here or only strand for timer(s)

Comment: Who said your solution with post is wrong? For one thing, I don't see any code,  so it's hard to tell whether something is wrong. Even if you have 1 thread tunning io_service::run, it implies that *external* calls must be from another thread so indeed you have to synchronize access to your shared IO objects. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/12801042/85371