# Beast SSL Stream Shutdown During Handshake

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, boost-beast

I am using beast for implementation of HTTPS Client. In order to make the handshake I call `async_handshake`. But if I try to shutdown the stream via `async_shutdown`, I receive the following assert: `` boost::beast::detail::stream_base::pending_guard::pending_guard(bool&): Assertion `! b_' failed. ``
Is there a way to correctly shutdown the stream during the handshake?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the assertion means that a read/write operation is in progress. Make sure you synchronize access to the stream object using a (implicit) strand.

If you have only one thread, you should already have it. Otherwise, post to the strand executor, e.g. instead of

```
stream_.async_shutdown(handler);
```

Do something like

```
boost::asio::post(stream_.get_executor(),
     [self] { self->stream_.async_shutdown(handler); });
```

If the containing class has shared ownership you would have `auto self = shared_from_this();`. Otherwise `self` could just be `this`.

More background on where and why of strands: [Asio docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html) and [Why do I need strand per connection when using boost::asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042)

Comment: Everything is executed on the single thread

Comment: Just to check where and how do you run the io_context?

Comment: If we skip the details of implementation, context is created in the main function and the rest of the code is called inside post function

Comment: There was just 1 thing I wanted to check: _where_ do you `run()` it? I'm assuming directly in main.

Comment: Yes, you are right