# ASIO / ARM: What might cause "Bad Address" (EFAULT) error after a random number of async_write() calls with a memory-mapped DMA buffer?

Tags: c++, arm, buffer, boost-asio, dma

I have a C++ program that reads data from a 65,536 byte (64 KiB) memory-mapped buffer managed by [udmabuf](https://github.com/ikwzm/udmabuf). This Linux kernel driver allows the buffer to be located at a known address in physical memory and yet accessible to Linux User Space via `/dev/udmabuf0`. My program uses Boost 1.74 ASIO to perform `async_write()` to a socket, to send this data to a connected client elsewhere (the client is fast and can drain the socket faster than this host can fill it).

Apologies, it's too complicated to provide compilable code, but I'll try my best to explain my program.

The code runs on an ARM Cortex-A53, cross-compiled by g++. There's some hardware that is programmed to perform a DMA write to the buffer, and on completion, the data from the buffer (which is mmapped as `O_SYNC` and passed as `buffer_mm`) is written to the network socket using a function like this:

```
class Session: public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
private:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;

...

public:
    void write_data(void * buffer_mm,
                    std::size_t total_bytes_transferred) {
        auto buffer = boost::asio::const_buffer(static_cast<const uint8_t *>(buffer_mm));

        boost::asio::async_write(
            socket_,
            buffer,
            [total_bytes_transferred, me = shared_from_this()]
                    (const error_code & ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
                if (ec) {
                    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "write_data [" << ec << "] " << ec.message();
                    // stop sending data.
                } else {
                    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "write_data " << bytes_transferred << " bytes";
                    // continue writing data...
                    me->write_footer(total_bytes_transferred + bytes_transferred);
                }
        });
    }
};
```

There are also simple `write_header()` and `write_footer()` functions that write some static data before and after this, but those `async_write()` calls never report the error I'm about to describe.

I have a loop that runs this sequence hundreds of times, filling the buffer via DMA, then writing the buffer's contents to the socket for the client to consume, as fast as possible (no introduced delays).

However, after a seemingly random number of iterations (sometimes as few as 5, sometimes as many as 50 or occasionally 100 or so), the `async_write()` calls the completion lambda function with the error "Bad Address".

As I understand it, the "Bad Address" error (system:14) means that the `async_write()` made a system call that returned `EFAULT`, indicating the syscall was passed an invalid pointer to user-space memory. This puzzles me because the `async_write()` function is being passed the exact same address (of the memory-mapped buffer) every iteration. It does not change! What would make it suddenly become a "bad address"?

As far as I can tell, the socket is in a good state at this moment in time, although I'm not sure how to determine this with 100% reliability.

I'm wondering if there's something fundamentally wrong with how I'm calling `async_write()`? Are my lifetimes correct?

Also, my `iocontext` is single-threaded and run simply:

```
boost::asio::io_context io_context_ {1};
...
io_context_.run();
```

Do I need to use a *strand* in this single-threaded situation? I had thought that was only needed for multi-threaded io_contexts.

If I put a 45ms delay before the `async_write()`, then the error does not occur. A delay slightly shorted than this (say, 40ms) tends to result in the error but less frequently. 35ms seems to have no effect on preventing the occurrence.

It also only breaks for a narrow range of transfer sizes near 65,536 (64 KiB). Four bytes more does not seem to generate this error, nor does 16 bytes fewer, but multiples of 4 in-between do. This translates to a broken range of 4-byte aligned lengths between [65524, 65536].

The underlying buffer size doesn't matter it seems, only the size of the data passed to `async_write()`.

I'm using the default cache configuration of udmabuf - `O_SYNC` disables the CPU cache, and as far as I can tell, the data from the buffer is transferred to the socket without going via the CPU, because I can achieve almost 900 Mbps network throughput.

Also, I'm using `async_write()` not synchronous `write()` because this actually fits into a larger program where other `async_write()` operations may be taking place. I do have a version written using synchronous `write()` and the same error occurs.

Any ideas please?

---

**EXTRA:**

I've just remembered something that might be relevant. When I first wrote this code some months ago, I was trying to combine the header, data and footer into a single `async_write()` call by putting the pointers to these blocks of data into a scatter/gather-style `std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer>`, and passing this vector to `async_write()`. I had a lot of problems with the alignment of data following the header - if the header wasn't a multiple of 4 bytes then the call would *sometimes* return "Bad Address". It wouldn't always do this and it seemed highly stateful. I wasn't able to work out the exact triggering pattern. To work around this, I padded the header out to a multiple of 4 bytes, but that ended up breaking my protocol. So in the end I modified the code to make three separate `async_write()` calls for the header, data and footer, and the issue seemed to go away. Until now...

Does this behaviour ring any bells for anyone reading this? Could it be related? Except the header/footer aren't changing...

---

**NEW INFORMATION:**

I've discovered two things that may be relevant:

1. When the "Bad Address" occurs during a 65,536 byte write, it's always after writing 32,737 bytes, according to the `size_t bytes_transferred` parameter is when the `async_write()` completion handler is called. I determined that it's a legitimate count of bytes transmitted because the receiving client can read exactly this many bytes from its socket before it is exhausted.
2. If I change *all* of my writes to this socket, throughout my entire program, to always be multiples of 8 bytes, then the problem completely goes away. This messes up my protocol with padding somewhat, but I was able to get everything working 100% reliably by doing this.
3. It's not very deterministic. I have some tests that can trigger the "Bad Address" condition, and they seem to be the only tests that do this, but they don't trigger it most of the time, yet the inputs are the same each time. So it seems to happen under "random chance". Sometimes it happens 50% of the time, and sometimes I can run error-free tests over and over, making me think it's gone away completely, until it happens. This makes me suspect there's some internal system state at play.

So what's the significance of the number 32,737? It's 31 shy of 32,768.

Comment: "Do I need to use a strand in this single-threaded situation? I had thought that was only needed for multi-threaded io_contexts." - no you don't need a strand then https://stackoverflow.com/a/12801042/85371

Answer (score 1):

The mmap is probably fine. It does seem like an alignment issue, which *does* happen om ARM. (x86/x64 architectures are forgiving in the sense that they don't hard-fail, but the performance degrades significantly).

Alignment should not be an in issue in the IO operations themselves (unless your OS/platform has additional documentation beyond [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html#tag_16_685).

Alignment issues will usually arise when you use an address as-if pointing to an integral type > 1 byte. I'd expect the alignment might need to be larger than 4 bytes on you target architecture, so that's a first place to check.

> A cursory check does confirm 32-bit aligment is ok https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0500/d/programmers-model/about-the-programmers-model/modes-of-operation?lang=en

---

### About Scatter/gather interface

Scatter/gather writes should change much - if the individual buffers in the sequence are properly aligned the behavior should be equivalent (and potentially more optimized).

According to docs the alignment requirements may be different due to the DMA backing: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0500/d/cortex-a53-processor-aarch32-unpredictable-behaviors/armv8-debug-unpredictable-behaviors/using-memory-access-mode-with-a-non-word-aligned-address

> #### Using memory-access mode with a non-word-aligned address The Cortex-A53 processor behaves as indicated in the sole Preference:
>
> - Does unaligned accesses, faulting if these are not permitted for the memory type.

If this is the case then scatter/gather failing might be due to some Asio implementation detail doing unsupported operations on non-word-aligned data inadvertently? If so, this would be a reportable bug: https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues

Comment: I also wondered if it had to do with CPU cache issues and DMA.  This can also be combined with alignment as a full cache line versus partial could cause some edge case behaviour as described by the trigger conditions.  There are ARM fault reason registers, so `dmesg` and proc may have more information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I suspect alignment too, now, on the side of the reads from the DMA buffer. In fact, I was able to make the issue "go away" (at least in one situation) by ensuring that both the header and footer had a length that was an integer multiple of 8-bytes, and the data (in the middle) an integer multiple of 4-bytes. I find it strange that the length of the header and footer affect the read from the DMA buffer but maybe it's related to how ASIO gathers data from multiple `async_write()` calls, since the data write would also be via DMA.

Comment: In the larger context, I still see the error because I have a lot of other messages sent to that socket that are not 8-byte multiples in length, and it seems that over some time this eventually affects this data write. Still experimenting...

Comment: @artlessnoise I'm not seeing any noise in `dmesg` - but I'll see if I can find the fault registers in `/proc`, maybe they will tell me something

Comment: @artlessnoise I haven't been able to monitor the ARM fault register during this behaviour because it does not generate any kind of `dmesg` output (no "Alignment trap" for example). I've also noted some new observations at the end of my question, specifically for a full-alignment workaround and the value 32,737 for `bytes_transferred`.

Comment: @sehe I've added some extra info to the end of my question, if that helps at all. I do think there's an alignment issue going on but it does seem to be difficult to catch - running the same tests over and over don't trigger it, until it does.

Comment: Try to attach a debugger and follow where the alignment trap actually happens https://davinci-linux-open-source.linux.davincidsp.com.narkive.com/kmL3pJyT/alignment-trap-problem

Comment: @sehe I think I'd have to debug the kernel, because there is no bus error or signal to the user process, the only symptom is that the return value of a system call (called by ASIO somewhere in the `io_context` as a result of `async_write()`) is EFAULT.

Now I'm wondering if I can trigger the problem in QEMU.

Comment: Aren't you overthinking that? If a kernel call results in a fault, it depends on the arguments. Perhaps a debugger with reverse/history can help spot where it is being called with the offending arguments.