# Is it safe to call APIs of ASIO objects concurrently?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm new to ASIO and like to understand how thread-safety works, so that I can figure out what assumptions I can make when using ASIO APIs.

**What I found out so far:**

Multiple threads can run `io_service.run()`.

Therefore, the handlers within a class such as `socket`, might be invoked
from different threads, but only from the threads that execute `io_service.run()`.

Let's assume that a `socket` has some internal state that must be protected
from concurrent access.

The `socket` would wrap its handlers with a `strand`, which serializes the execution
of the handlers. It has essentially the same effect as acquiring a mutex in each 
handler, but with better performance.

But `socket` also has public methods, such as `socket.async_write_some()`. It
too might be invoked from different threads.

Let's assume that `socket.async_write_some()` accesses the same internal state,
so some protection mechanism is needed.

**How do public methods access the internal state in a safe way?**

- can `strand` be used to serialize invocations of public methods?
- invoke `post([]{ /* actual implementation of the method goes here */})` within the public method?
- use a mutex in addition to the strand?

**What assumptions can I make when invoking public APIs?**

Can I assume that a `socket` protects it's internal state, even if I invoke it from a background thread that does not invoke `io_service.run()`?

If so, is there some documentation for that? I'd rather not depend on an undocumented implementation detail.

Comment: In other words, you ask how to learn asio, exact ?


Anyway look [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244453/best-documentation-for-boostasio/26753331#26753331) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042) and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the thread safety guarantees, which are documented with each class, but also in general https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html

This confirms that:

> Q. Can I assume that a socket protects it's internal state, even if I invoke it from a background thread that does not invoke io_service.run()?

No you can not assume that, because it doesn't "protect it's  internal state" in the sense you likely mean: it does not synchronize access to it.

Also, access from *multiple threads* running `io_service` handlers does *no* mean it's safe. You may need `strands` (either implicit or explicit) to ensure that.

Comment: I used the c++11 thread_local scope on my io_service, worked well for me.  I'm assuming it is safe to have multiple io_service objects.  Perhaps I should have used strands...?

Comment: @moodboom The `io_service` is one of the few Asio objects that's actually documented to be thread-safe for concurrent use. So, no it doesn't make a lot of sense to have that `thread_local` (also, that's not a scope, but a lifetime or storage duration). You CAN have multiple io_services, but they won't do anything unless you `run()` or` `poll()` on them.

Comment: yeah you're right, i was smoking crack, i don't use thread_local on io_service, sorry.  i do have several io_service objects, but only one main one, and others that I stand up for temporary use, for example to make outbound https calls.  now i'm thinking maybe i should share the one even with the outbound https calls.  anyway, i'm getting too chatty in the comments, sorry.