# Understanding boost::asio::post with single callable - who executes?

Tags: c++, c++17, boost-asio

I would like to know how I should understand [`boost::asio::post`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/post/overload1.html)

In particular this overload that can just take a single *callable*, who/what/where executes it now (since I don't explicit pass it an `io_service`/`io_context` for example) ?

Does it just randomly (more or less) choose a running `io_service` (if there is one) ? I feel like there is something Im completely missing.

Comment: It does say _"Obtains the handler's associated executor object `ex` by performing `get_associated_executor(handler)`"_ at the bottom of your own link. Does that answer the question? If not, are you really just asking what `get_associated_executor` returns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually, boost::asio::post will use `get_associated_executor` to look up a specialization of [`associated_executor`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/associated_executor.html).  The default implementation will provide a static instance of [`system_executor`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/system_executor.html), where the object will be invoked.

Comment: It does leave me wondering still, I do not know about system_executor or associated_executor - parhaps, can you elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: also system_executor does sound unsuitable for my purpose as it mentions a thread pool, I need everything to run on same thread (thus avoiding sync'ing) !

Comment: @darune May be you simply need to learn the basis of asio ... [Best documentation for Boost:asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244453/best-documentation-for-boostasio)

Comment: @Darune I've personally never had a use case for the single argument version of `post`, as I always want to specify the executor to run on.  It seems to exist when you want to route certain handlers to static executors based on type.  Obviously the implementors of ASIO felt it was something useful.  Getting into how to use ASIO more fully is a bit beyond the scope of a single Stack overflow question.

Comment: @DaveS Thanks, I see, I also ended up using that version - the single argument would perhaps be more usefull if it guarendteed same thread/io_context (or that would be a configuration)

Answer (score 1):

[Dave S's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64334315/267482) is correct, but if a writer of the code is confused with the default signature, imagine what will happen to a reader! Maybe better to just use [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/post/overload2.html) or [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/post/overload3.html) overload with explicit execution context argument instead.

Comment: I've +1-ed this for _mentioning_ the explicit executor overloads. Don't forget, though, that in many cases the implicit "magic" behaviour (with associated executors) is precisely what you /want to/ have (e.g. when the task is a strand-wrapped completion handler, and you can't know which strand it belongs to. This is where associated executors become very powerful)